# Measure pipe throughput in the shell

Tags: command-line, pipe, performance, io

There is a shell command that allows you to measure how fast the data goes through it, so you can measure the speed of output of commands in a pipe. So instead of:

```
$ somecommand | anothercommand
```

you can do something like:

```
$ somecommand | ??? | anothercommand
```

And throughput stats (bytes/sec) are printed to stderr, I think. But I can't for the life of me remember what that command was.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[cpipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1537/measure-pipe-throughput-in-the-shell/1538#1538) is probably better for these purposes, but another related program is [pv](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) (Pipe Viewer):

[image: Screenshot of pv from the pv homepage]

If you give it the `--rate` flag it will show the transfer rate

Answer (score 20):

You need a utility called [cpipe](http://cpipe.berlios.de/).

Usage:

```
tar cCf / - usr | cpipe -vr -vw -vt > /dev/null
```

Output:

```
...
  in:  19.541ms at    6.4MB/s (   4.7MB/s avg)    2.0MB
 out:   0.004ms at   30.5GB/s (  27.1GB/s avg)    2.0MB
thru:  19.865ms at    6.3MB/s (   4.6MB/s avg)    2.0MB
...
```

Comment: No longer found any valid reference to `cpipe`... but `pv` is equivalent.

Comment: Is there a similar command for windows, or is there any `pv` that is windows compatible ?

Answer (score 3):

As seen at https://askubuntu.com/a/620234, notice that `pv`, at least, can slow down your throughput significantly.  The article linked to covers `dd`, but the point is that `pv` can slow down your stuff. If you care, and if you are transferring terabytes of data for example.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Python 2 or 3 and pip (`sudo apt-get install python-pip`) you can install `tqdm`:

```
    python -m pip install tqdm
```

Then simply:

```
    somecommand | tqdm | anothercommand
```

If you need help, run `tqdm --help`. It has **a lot** of options. Feel free to read more and make suggestions at https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm

Answer (score 0):

A new tool is now available to inspect already running processes files access, display progress and throughput estimation: https://github.com/Xfennec/cv

If your `somecommand` or `anothercommand` are already known by `cv`, it is just as easy to use as `watch cv -wq`, or else you have to use `-c` option to monitor specifically your processes.