# How can I move files and view the progress (e.g. with a progress bar)?

Tags: command-line, mv, progress-information

When moving large directories using `mv`, is there a way to view the progress (%)?
The `cp` command on gentoo had a `-g` switch that showed the progress.

Comment: [Measure pipe throughput in the shell](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1537/measure-pipe-throughput-in-the-shell/1539#1539) might help, although I don't know if it's possible to easily use those tools when moving a file

Comment: related: [copy with progress](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56047/progress-information-via-pv-for-directory-copy/329594#329594), [delete with progress](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327298/deleting-billions-of-files-from-a-directory-while-seeing-the-progress-as-well/327311#327311), [compare with progress](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111251/compare-massive-directories-with-progress-report/329608#329608), [rsync with progress](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188758/estimate-time-or-work-left-to-finish-for-rsync/329603#329603).

Comment: i prefer `rsync -aAX --info=progress2` (copy with progress info single totals bar, -a --archive mode: recursive, copies symlinks, keeps permissions, times, owner, group, device. -A acls -X extended attributes.) `alias cpr='rsync -aAX --info=progress2 '`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can build a patched cp and mv which then both support the -g switch to show progress. There are instructions and patches at [this page](https://github.com/jarun/advcpmv). **However**: The page instructs you to do

```
$ sudo cp src/cp /usr/bin/cp
$ sudo cp src/mv /usr/bin/mv
```

which overwrites the original cp and mv. This has two disadvantages: Firstly, if an updated coreutils package arrives at your system, they are overwritten. Secondly, if the patched version has a problem, they might break scripts relying on standard cp and mv. I would rather do something like this:

```
$ sudo cp src/cp /usr/local/bin/cpg
$ sudo cp src/mv /usr/local/bin/mvg
```

which copies the files to /usr/local/bin which is intended for user compiled programs and gives them a different name. So when you want a progress bar, you say `mvg -g bigfile /mnt/backup` and use mv normally.

Also you can do `alias mvg="/usr/local/mvg -g"` then you only need to say `mvg bigfile /mnt/backup` and directly get the progress bar.

Comment: Unfortunately the patch on “this page” is no longer present and doesn't appear to have been indexed in the Web Archive. There appear to be [many patches with a similar name and function](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4064/what-can-we-normal-users-can-do-with-an-accepted-answer-that-contains-dead-lin/4068#4068), could you edit your answer to clarify which one you meant?

Comment: I think https://github.com/atdt/advcpmv is a valid successor and it has the same patch so I changed the link to point to it.

Comment: @fschmitt: this link is no longer valid (404) but there is https://github.com/jarun/advcpmv . is this similar to what you linked to?

Answer (score 191):

There's a new tool called `progress` that can find any descriptor related to a running command and show progress and speed:
[available here](https://github.com/Xfennec/progress)

```
progress -w
```

outputs the stats for all running cp,mv etc. operations

Comment: WOW, I did not expect this to be so awesome! I simply typed `progress` after installing and it presented me with progress for the `mv` command I was currently waiting for. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! When moving stuff as a root it seems you have to use `sudo` (same user I guess) - you can also use `watch` to say what is happening every 2 seconds: `watch progress -w`

Comment: Awesome program, but when moving e.g. a folder with many files it only shows the progress of the current file, not the whole folder in total. Instead of `watch progress -w` you can also simply use `progress -m`

Comment: IMHO, this is the most unix-way to solve the problem. Instead of patching coreutils or using tools which are not designated for specific purposes (like rsync for mv) or writing overkilling scripts, just use that tool written for the subject purpose with love.

Comment: The best solution, intuitive. When using `rsync` I always catch myself on checking `man rsync`..

Answer (score 107):

I don't like the idea to overwrite binaries from coreutil when there are simpler solutions, so here are mine:

**rsync**: Rsync copies files and has a `-P` switch for a progress bar. So if you have rsync installed, you could use a simple alias in your shells dotfile:

```
alias cp='rsync -aP'
```

The downside is, that rsync is a little bit slower than cp, but you should measure this with time and decide for your self, I can live with it :-)

**Shell Script**: A shell script can also create the progress bar. I found this a while ago on the net and I don't remember the source:

```
#!/bin/sh
cp_p()
{
   strace -q -ewrite cp -- "${1}" "${2}" 2>&1 \
      | awk '{
        count += $NF
            if (count % 10 == 0) {
               percent = count / total_size * 100
               printf "%3d%% [", percent
               for (i=0;i<=percent;i++)
                  printf "="
               printf ">"
               for (i=percent;i<100;i++)
                  printf " "
               printf "]\r"
            }
         }
         END { print "" }' total_size=$(stat -c '%s' "${1}") count=0
}
```

This will look like:

```
% cp_p /home/echox/foo.dat /home/echox/bar.dat
66% [===============================>                      ]
```

**bar**:

> ‘bar’ - ‘cat’ with ASCII progress bar

`bar` is a small shell script to display a process bar for all kind of operations (cp, tar, etc.). You can find examples on the [project homepage.](http://www.theiling.de/projects/bar.html)

Its also written for the bourne shell, so it will run nearby everywhere.

Comment: `bar` doesn't wrap `mv` yet.

Comment: Credit for the [shell script](http://chris-lamb.co.uk/2008/01/24/can-you-get-cp-to-give-a-progress-bar-like-wget/)

Comment: Note that `rsync` doesn't replace `mv` (the OP is asking about) completely, especially when it comes to fast copies on copy-on-write filesystems like `btrfs`.

Comment: Does it work for `mv` ?

Comment: I have "nmv" aliased locally to `rsync -a --stats --progress --remove-source-files`.  There are different flags you may want to set to control local caching, intermediate compression, etc., depending on your setup.

Comment: I support your answer, but I'm wondering if aliasing something as fundamental as 'cp' could have some extremely rare unintended consequence down the road. Like I see these people trying to "unshadow" aliases https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39357/8234 and I'm wondering if I use your solution, will other applications mistakenly use rsync instead of cp?

Answer (score 46):

You can use [pipe viewer](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) command `pv` to show progress bar:

```
pv /original/file > /new/file
```

I often use this to copy a big file over a mounted network filesystem (combine with `gzip` and `tar`). The drawback is that you can only copy *one* file and not directory. And you must give the new file a name, you can not just give destination directory like `cp` does. However copying is not `pv`'s purpose. It is a powerful tool and do much more than just copy file. See the homepage for more examples of `pv`.

A much better option is to use `rsync -aP`. If you want to `mv` instead, append the flag `--remove-source-files`. Add this to your `.bashrc` if you want to use the commands frequently:

```
alias rscp='rsync -aP'
alias rsmv='rsync -aP --remove-source-files'
```

The downside here is rsync only shows progress, not a progress bar.

Comment: `tar cf - source-dir | pv | tar xf - -C out-dir` will give you throughput of a whole directory.  If you know the size and pass `-s` to pv it can give you progress as well.

Answer (score 10):

If your goal is to move/copy a directory with progress bar, but avoiding non-terminal GUI, mc (Midnight Commander) is a good choice.

Answer (score 8):

My solution is to use `rsync`. It can copy directories, remove the source files after a successful copy (thus "moving" them) and display progress reports, among many other features (most notably syncing partially copied directories and working over the network.)

Here is how I would move a directory with rsync, with progress report:

```
rsync -aP --remove-source-files $src $dst && rm -r $src
```

Make sure `$src` does ***not*** end in a backslash, otherwise you will get a different meaning than that of GNU `cp`.

The `rm -r` at the end is needed because `--remove-source-files` only removes the source files, after each one is successfully copied over, not the directories. The `&&` makes sure to run it only if rsync completes successfully. If you are paranoid, you can replace it with some kind of recursive `rmdir`, such as `find $src -d -exec rmdir {} +`

The only glitch is that the `-P` option shows progress for each file, not for the entire copy operation. This might be useless if you are trying to move a directory with many tiny files. The latest development version of rsync has an alternate flag `--info=progress2` that shows progress for the entire operation.

Answer (score 4):

This does not give you a progress bar, but hit `CTRL-T` and you will send a `SIGINFO` to `mv`, which will report which file it's working on and how far along in the process it is. Pretty handy to have this for large file transfers, possibly not as useful for a transfer with many small files.

Quick example:

```
mv 135/61 /Volumes/Jules/135/
# hit C-t
load: 1.08  cmd: cp 35470 uninterruptible 0.00u 0.04s
135/61/1/1-s2.0-S006738-main.pdf -> /Volumes/Jules/135/61/1/1-s2.0-S006738-main.pdf  68%
```

Comment: This didn't work for me:  I got `INFO: unknown signal; killall -l lists signals.`  I think SIGINFO is only on some BSDs, not in standard POSIX.

Comment: Right. It does work in Mac OS X, but likely not in, say, Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

```
mv -v sourcedir targetdir | pv -l -s filecount > logfile
```

You will need `pv` (pipe viewer): http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml

`mv -v` will print one line per moved file and `pv -l` will report progress based on line count.

Use the following command to get file count:

```
find sourcedir | wc -l
```

This command will show progress information based on number of files copied. This works best if there are many smallish files. If there are only a few files which are huge then you will not have much fun.

---

For more alternatives, including methods which can report progress based on size, see here: [progress information via pv for directory copy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56047/progress-information-via-pv-for-directory-copy/329594#329594)

Methods described there all copy the files instead of moving. but unless you are moving on the same filesystem a move is practically a copy followed by a delete.

Answer (score 3):

Invariably I end up searching for this answer *after* I start the 'mv' command, at which point I don't want to start it again. If you're in this situation a very simple way to monitor the progress (or to see if it's far enough along that it's not worth killing) is to run:

```
du -hs /directory/you're/moving/data/to
```

This will just print the size of the directory so you can see how much data has been copied, or you can run it a couple of times to see how fast the data is being transfered.

Comment: if you're moving a lot of data the `du` command itself will also take quite some time to compute the size at dest

Answer (score 2):

To avoid coreutil patching to add progress bar to `mv` and `cp`, `gcp` (Goffi's CoPier) is a new alternative: http://wiki.goffi.org/wiki/Gcp/en

To use the same way as `cp` with options `-r` for recursivity and `-v` for verbosity.

It uses a file queue when multiple commands are invoked concurrently. It also allows to record copied file names in a log, see *Source saving* man page section for details.

Here is a good tutorial to get started with `gcp`: http://mylinuxbook.com/gcp-advanced-command-line-file-copier-inspired-by-cp/

Comment: Is there gmv like gcp for cp?

Comment: I have found no equivalent. By the way, there is no need for progress bar when running "mv" on a single file system... it is quite fast. If move is done across two different file systems, it is implemented as cp and then remove source if succeed, or remove target if failed. A simple shell script based on gcp may do it properly (with a first check to know if source and target are really on different file systems)

Answer (score 2):

On my Mint I like to use  gcp on this or the curl-solution (which is really nice)

```
gcp SOURCE DESTINATION
```

You might need to install it `sudo apt-get install gcp`

And a very nice and excellent task for the progress bar with info about

- % Total
- % Received
- % Xferd
- Average DL
- Speed  Upload
- Time left
- Time spent
- Time total
- Current Speed

in a nice readable format is:

```
curl -o DESTINATION FILE://source
```

Also, you might need to install it first `sudo apt-get install curl`

Comment: `gcp` doesn't support moving of file, i.e. source files have to be removed manually after successful copying.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following script saved with `rsmv` name:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

rsync -aP --remove-source-files "$@" && rm -rf "${@:1:$#-1}"
```

It handles more then one source and filenames with whitespaces:

```
$ rsmv source1 source2 source\ 3 "source 4" dest
```

Comment: Doesn't `--remove-source-files` accomplish the removal? Why is the `&& rm ...`  there?

Comment: This is otherwise very similar to existing answers: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184943/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/15656/117549

Comment: `--remove-source-files` removes only files. So if source arguments contains directories then they will not be deleted. `rm ...` handles deletion of such directories.

Comment: Yep, it's improved version that is closer to mv, because it handles many source arguments.

Comment: Be very very careful if you have symbolic links and are moving an entire dir transfer (i.e. `rsync --remove-source-files A/* B/`). If `B/` is a symlink to `A/` you will lose everything in `A/` whereas with `mv` you would not. It happens to me once every 12 months or so and I keep having to use `extundelete` to undo the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

First off: I never copy large files without using ionice, unless I know that I will not want to use the computer for half an hour or more.

Second: all my partitions are jouranled so intrapartition copying takes not time. If it is a long copy I do a `du -sm` on the files and `df -m | grep copy_to_partition`. Then if curious how much more time it will take I do the `df` again and see how much of the files was copied.

Comment: Would you care to share your ionice tips ? what priority would you give to mv cpu-wise and disk i/o wise ? Here are my settings but the CPU load is still high even after renicing : https://imgur.com/a/DLMJplz

Answer (score 1):

On mac you can open Activity Monitor and go to the Disk tab, look for the process 'mv' in the list and look at 'Bytes Written'. That shows how far through the transfer is.

Not an exact solution but it does put your mind at ease to know your transfer is working and you can see the approximate speed.