# how to create progress bar during copy files

Tags: file-copy

I need to copy huge files in my Linux machine.

Example:

```
cp source.txt target.txt
```

I want to create bar progress that will show that copy still in progress on each copy file

Examples"

```
cp file file1
```

copy file > file1 .........

```
cp moon mars
```

copy moon > mars .......

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, you won't find `cp` native functionality for progress bar output.  Why?  [Many reasons](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15655/why-doesnt-cp-have-a-progress-bar-like-wget).  However, you have some options:

1. Use a different tool.  `rsync`, as mentioned by @user1404316 has `--progress`:

   ```
   rsync -P largeFile copyLocation
   ```
2. If you don't need the extra semantics that `cp` and `rsync` take care of, create a new file with `pv` ("Pipe Viewer") by redirecting `stdout`:

   ```
   pv < largeFile > copyLocation
   ```
3. If you **do** need the extra semantics, you can use `progress`, though it doesn't give the bar specifically.  It attaches to *already running* processes, so you would invoke it like:

   ```
   # In one shell
   $ cp largeFile copyLocation

   # In another shell
   $ progress -m
   [ 4714] cp /home/hunteke/largeFile
           1.1% (114 MiB / 10.2 GiB)      # -m tells progress to continually update
   ```
4. Another option is `gcp`, which does exactly what you've requested with a progress bar:

   ```
   gcp largeFile copyLocation
   ```
5. Another option abuses `curl`'s ability to handle `file://` urls:

   ```
   curl -o copyLocation file:///path/to/largeFile
   ```
6. You can write a shell script

Comment: why not use like this pv largeFile > copyLocation ( not as mentioned pv < largeFile > copyLocation )

Comment: regarding the gcp , I not found for centos

Comment: @yael mild semantic difference.  Yours will continue where a previous copy left off.  The mentioned version mimics `cp`'s standard overwrite behavior.

Comment: I download the pv , and I see that copy is very fast it take much less then cp , so my question is dose pv copy the source to target with high reliability

Comment: Not knowing your exact command, I'm surprised at the speed difference.  The underlying mechanism doing the copying in both cases is the kernel.  `cp` may be doing some extra CRC or other checks, but I doubt it.  What `cp` will do that `pv` won't, especially with `-a`, is maintain `stat` properties, like time modified, ownership (if you're running as `root`), etc.

Answer (score 1):

`rsync` is a copy program that has great features for copying huge files, including a `--progress` feature, and it has a form of in-transit compression to reduce the data in transit (and thus saving time for the copy):

```
rsync --progress file1 file2
```

`rsync` also has features to resume a copy that was interrupted, maybe due to a network disconnection. You would need to start it with options `--partial --append-verify`. The only downside that I can think of to using `rsync` for copying over a network is that it needs to have been installed on both computers, ie. the sender and the receiver. See its `man` page for details and all its other features...

If you can't install `rsync` for some reason, or don't want to, a good simple alternative is `pv`, a *pipe viewer* command, that does exactly what you are asking for.

```
pv from-file > to-file
```

`pv` also includes *many* visualization options. See its `man` page for all the goodies available. Here are some of the commonly used options:

```
-p, --progress
-t, --timer
-e, --eta
-r, --rate
-a, --average-rate
-b, --bytes
```

Comment: pv is great , can we say that pv is affected exactly like cp?  or cp -r or cp -rp ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. They are different commands, so no, options specific to `cp` won't exist for `pv` unless the man page for `pv` says so.