# how to create progress bar when running command that take time

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, awk

how to create progress bar when running command that take time

for example ( this take 10 min )

```
cat GTTfiles* > GTTcentos7.tar.gz
```

so during that CLI is working how to create some progress that show process is running?

example of output ,  ( only example , we will happy to get other ideas )

```
 |..........                             |
```

Comment: Note that `pv`, which is mentioned in the linked duplicate and the answers to [your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/426849/86440), can do this accurately if it’s told about the total size of the files to copy.

Comment: can you show me please the syntax with pv?

Comment: Have you tried looking at its documentation?