# Is there a command line utility that copy files with progress information?

Tags: command-line, file-copy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [move files with progress bar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2577/move-files-with-progress-bar)

cp gets the job done but it would be nice if it had a little more feedback. Are there any utilities out there that do this? Personally, my ideal feedback would be a progress bar. But, I would take something as basic as output listing the files being copied as they are completed.

Thanks!

Comment: `rsync --progress`?  http://mpov.timmorgan.org/use-rsync-instead-of-cp

Answer (score 1):

1. [gcp](http://wiki.goffi.org/wiki/Gcp/en) has a integrated progress bar
2. `rsync` with the `--progress` option will show you the current file being copied
3. [pv](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) supports progress bars. You can do something like `pv source > target`

Of course there are plenty of other ways to do the same (like using strace to hook into cp or patching the original cp)