# Run a command that is shadowed by an alias

Tags: bash, shell, alias

Let's say I have the following alias in bash - `alias ls='ls --color=auto'` - and I want to call ordinary `ls` without options. Is the only way to do that is to unalias, do the command and then alias again? Or there is some nifty trick or workaround?

Comment: Just a note about some of the answers below: "command" is the ONLY safe way to accomplish this.  For example, the "." or "source" built-in maybe be overridden by a script-defined function.  "command ." or "command source" is the only way to safely execute source without the script-defined function being invoked instead.  None of the other alternatives, including the backslash method "\.", work, and of course there is no "/bin/source" alternative that you can invoke by specifying a full path.

Answer (score 286, accepted):

You can also prefix a back slash to disable the alias: `\ls`

Edit: Other ways of doing the same include:

Use "command": `command ls` as per [Mikel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39302/9427).

Use the full path: `/bin/ls` as per [uther](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39292/9427).

Quote the command: `"ls"` or `'ls'` as per Mikel comment.

You can remove the alias temporarily for that terminal session with `unalias command_name`.

Comment: very nice, also works well with tcsh

Comment: This way is very useful.  It only bypasses aliases, not functions, which makes it different from `command` or `builtin`.

Comment: It seems like `l\s` does the same thing. Is this behaviour a bug or a feature?

Comment: It's a "feature".  Only unquoted aliases are expanded.  So you can put it in quotes, or use a backslash anywhere you like.  See [bash aliases reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html#Aliases).

Comment: @NotNow: Care to incorporate the other options (like `"ls"` or `'ls'`) into your answer? Would be useful to have this as reference.

Comment: Just for the record `which ls` is not really reliable as it may return the aliased command

Comment: works also for zsh

Comment: I'd [remove the `which` recommendation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10525/how-to-use-which-on-an-aliased-command), and possibly replace it with `type` instead.

Comment: In case these solutions aren't working, do `type -a ls` to troubleshoot. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39291/run-a-command-that-is-shadowed-by-an-alias/663608#663608

Answer (score 102):

That's what the `command` command is for.

Try

```
command ls
```

This tells the shell to bypass aliases and functions.

This way is supported by [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html), [zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-command-1), and [ash](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sh&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+9.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html)/dash.

Comment: Because it adds 8 times the number of characters as the *backslash* method

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED This also doesn't work with tcsh (and therefore presumably not with csh either). The `\\` method does

Comment: @Levon: the question was asked for `bash`, though ;) ... see the tags. And the reason the other one works is a quirk, nothing else.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED ah .. good point re the tag, didn't notice it. Glad the \ works (quirk or not) .. that'll come in useful.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED Thanks for defending my answer. But bash has many quirks, so provided the backslash method is a feature and not a bug, I think it's also a good answer. In fact it's documented in the [bash aliases reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html#Aliases).

Comment: The backslash feature is not secure.  While it provides protection against similarly-named aliases, it does not provide protection against similarly-named functions.

Comment: @JoelFan I'd much rather have the few extra characters and have my scripts be easy to follow and work for everyone. Rather than a cryptic slash which is not intuitive, easy to miss, not well documented, and doesn't work for bypassing functions.

Comment: note: `command` works great when its there (such as on fedora) but i was seeing that some distros do not appear to have it. i didn't see it after running `sudo find -type f -iname 'command'` under the bin or usr dirs on my linux mint partition (searching from fedora). if writing x-distro scripts, this may not be the best option

Comment: @zpangwin It's not a regular binary so `find` won't find it. [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins) [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html)

Comment: @ Mikel, you are absolutely correct, my bad. I had thought it was just a binary bc fedora-33 has a binary at /usr/bin/command. After looking at docs and running `type command` from within each distro separately, it is indeed a builtin on both systems despite fedora also having a binary. I also discovered another method which is *not* portable. On Fedora, it has `GNU which v2.21` and that supports the options `--skip-alias` and `--skip-functions`. Unfortunately, LM 20 (and presumably Ubuntu 20/Debian 10) are using a different version of `which` that does NOT support these (or even `--version`)

Answer (score 20):

The alias is just a defined shortcut. In this example, the alias defined is the string `ls`, which executes `ls --color=auto`. If you don't want that behavior, you can call the binary `ls` using the absolute path.

So executing just `/bin/ls` will produce output without color because it is not the alias you defined.

You could also change the alias to something different, or add a new alias that executes just `ls` without the color parameters.

Comment: You have to know where the command is. On some systems, the division between `/bin` and `/usr/bin` is arbitrary.

Comment: @KeithThompson For that, you could use `which` for some commands: `which ls`.

Comment: @cst1992: If you're going to use `which` (or `type`), it does a lookup via `$PATH`; you might as well just use `ls` or `\ls` rather than specifying the path.

Comment: @cst1992 I know the OP is about Bash, but on `zsh`, both `which`  and `command -v` or its human-readable `command -V` return the alias versions. Using `\ls` just works, but to get its real path I can only seem to think of `echo "$PATH" | tr ':' '\n' | xargs -I{} find {} -maxdepth 1 -name 'ls' -type f 2>/dev/null | head -n1`... which works.

Answer (score 10):

Another way, building upon @uther's answer, is to use `$(which ...)` or `` `which ...` `` (using backticks ``` `` ```) to automatically find the executable's path. This will work in `bash`:

```
$(which ls)

`which ls`
```

Undoubtedly, simply prefixing the command with a `\` is much shorter.

**UPDATE**: According to [How to use `which` on an aliased command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10525/19205), this doesn't seem to be reliable at all.

Comment: What's the brackets for?
I guess you mean `\`which ls\`` to execute the binary directly.

Comment: @amyassin: Both syntaxes are equivalent. (BTW, how did you get the backticks into the code formatting?)

Comment: Actually the `(which ls)` didn't work for me (on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)
And the backticks were hard, I just escaped them:
\\`which ls\\`. It took a lot of editing to get there :)

Comment: @user946850 "To include a literal backtick character within a code span, you can use multiple backticks as the opening and closing delimiters". Source: [Markdown Reference](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax).

Comment: @amyassin: Did you add the `$`?

Comment: @user946850 Ahaa,, I thought the `$` sign was for demonstrating the shell..

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I just avoid defining aliases with the same names as commands, so `ls` always invokes the actual command. I have aliases or functions for various combinations of options like `l`, `ll`, and `lg`. (This means I need `unalias ls` in my `.bashrc` or `.cshrc`.)

I find that the OS's assumptions about which options I might prefer (overriding the assumptions of the designers of the `ls` command itself) rarely match my own personal tastes. I happen to dislike the look of `ls --color=auto`, and its legibility can vary greatly between black-on-white and white-on-black.

YMMV, and the other solutions are of course still good to know.

Comment: I think this is a good strategy, because what if 'ls' is aliased and then some other random script needs/expects the original behavior, but accidentally uses the "shadowed" ls?

Answer (score 4):

If `\ls` and `command ls` are "not working", use `type -a ls` to troubleshoot what is happening.

In my case, `\ls` and `command ls` were returning nothing, and I was going crazy trying to figure out why. Turns out I somehow had a zero-byte file named `ls` in one of my paths, `~/bin`.

I was able to fix the situation by deleting `~/bin/ls`. Then `hash -d ls` to remove it from the hash table.

**Side note**:

`which -a ls` was not helpful because it only returned `/bin/ls`. Apparently, `which` cannot interpret the tilde in my path: `~/bin`. However `type -a ls` can.

Answer (score 1):

Typing the command in uppercase seems to work, like `LS`, though I'm not really sure why.

Comment: In which shell, which operating system, which terminal, etc.?

Comment: @Mikel There is a package "sl" that provides "sl" as "ls".  The tips bash gives in Ubuntu also say that "LS" is provided by "sl".

Comment: This is bash 4 (installed with Fink) in Mac OS X 10.7. It also works for other commands that I have aliased like rm and grep.

Comment: It's just a joke :)
from the mn page: `LS - display animations aimed to correct users who accidentally enter LS instead of ls.`

Comment: I think this works for Mac OS X because its filesystem is case-insensitive by default.  It won't work on other unixes.

Comment: @Jander that's likely it. Still, it's quite useful to take advantage of if you're on such a system.

Answer (score 0):

### For zsh

Order:

1. you type in the shell (stdin)
2. history expansion, such as `!!`, `!-3`
3. alias expansion (try <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> then <kbd>a</kbd>, to see the expanded result)
4. other expansions  (order: Process Substitution >  Parameter Expansion >  Command Substitution >  Arithmetic Expansion >  Brace Expansion)

---

suppose we have:

```bsh
alias pwd='echo "An Alias"'
```

then this function definition will get the error   `zsh: defining function based on alias 'pwd'`:

```
pwd(){ 
    echo "A function"
}
```

- alias expansion may be avoided by adding any kind of quoting to the word. If you want to use unaliased `pwd`, type `'pwd'`, `\pwd` or `"pwd"` (`pwd` is not regarded as quoting)
- `builtin pwd`  use zsh' s built-in function(aka command?) `pwd`
- `command pwd` use /bin/pwd,  (from GNU)

If there is no `alias pwd="echo WhatEver_blabla"`, and this  is in zshrc:

```
pwd(){ 
    echo "A function"
}
```

then quoting like `'pwd'` still calls this function.

But `command pwd` and `built pwd` work as expected

So we can have `alias rg="\rg --hiddeng"`,  but not  `rg(){ \rg --hidden}` (Otherwise we will meet such error :  maximum nested function level reached; increase FUNCNEST?)

ref:
man zshall