# what is `env <command>` doing?

Tags: shell, command-line, command, env

What is the command `env ls -al` doing?

I had a Linux test and there was question: "How to run command directly, but not its alias?"
I knew that there exists solution like prefixing command with some special symbol, but I forgot it. Now I know that it is `\`. (read from [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39291/run-a-command-that-is-shadowed-by-an-alias)).

But I also remember that somewhere I read that to get rid of alias we can prefix a command with `env`. I did it and it seems works, but my answer was qualified as wrong. 
I read `info` and `man` on `env`, but didn't understood too much.

What is `env` doing and exactly in `env <command>` without any arguments for `env` itself?

Comment: As a note, 3 ways of doing this that I can think of are `env <command>`, `command <command>`, and `\<command>`. In my opinion, if some test said `env <command>` is invalid, then that test is broken.

Comment: @Patrick: It is not broken because as Chris said, there could be an alias on `command` or `env` which would make `\\` the only acceptable answer.

Comment: @ArlaudPierre and `\\` isn't defined in posix (as an alias escape), so it's not portable. So it's no more acceptable than the others.

Comment: @Patrick: true, true. Now we'd have to know the exact perimeter of the test to say that. But in any case, find that the "env" answer is not an acceptable one isn't very honest, I'd have to agree with you on that.

Comment: Guys, test was verified by human too (LPI-certified ex-sysadmin, which teaching now others Linux) :) I complained to verifier, went to `man` and didn't understood what `env` exactly doing. After this post - it's clear and my answer was reviewed (accepted). 
Thanks to all!

Comment: @Patrick A backslash does avoid alias expansion in all POSIX shells: only unquoted words are subject to [alias substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_03_01). Other ways include `l\s`, `"l"s`, `ls''`, `ls$()`, …

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This command

```
env name=value name2=value2 program and args
```

runs the command `program and args` with an environment formed by extending the current environment with the environment variables and values designated by `name=value` and `name2=value2`. If you do not include any arguments like `name=value`, then the current environment is passed along unmodified.

The key thing that happens with respect to aliases is that *env* is an external command, so it has no “knowledge” of aliases: aliases are a shell construct that are not part of the normal process model and have no impact on programs that are directly run by non-shell programs (like *env*). *env* simply passes the `program and arguments` to an *exec* call (like *execvp*, which will search the PATH for `program`).

Basically, using *env* like this is a (mostly) shell-independent way of avoiding aliases, shell functions, shell builtin commands, and any other bits of shell functionality that might replace or override command-position arguments (i.e. program names)—unless, of course, `env` is an alias, or shell function! If you are worried about `env` being an alias, you could spell out the full path (e.g. `/usr/bin/env`, though it may vary).

Comment: why does a command such:
env MYVAR=3 echo $MYVAR
does not display anything?

Comment: @piertoni the `$MYVAR` is interpreted by your shell when you run the command, it's not deferred until `env` runs `echo`. Try eg. `env MYVAR=3 sh -c 'echo $MYVAR'`

Answer (score 29):

Another important use of `env` (apart from circumventing command alias lookup) is that it searches the `PATH` for the command. This is of importance where absolute paths are required, but vary from system to system.

For example, beginning a Bash script with `#!/bin/bash` is okay, whereas `#!bash` isn't, despite of `/bin` being included in the `PATH` on every reasonable system.

I frequently encountered this in Python programs, which usually begin with
`#!/usr/bin/env python` to avoid specifying the full, system-dependent path of the `python` executable (note, however, that it still requires that `env` resides in `/usr/bin`, this is however far more common than the location of the python binary).