# Bash shadow a command - function with same name as command

Tags: bash, command, alias

I have a function in my `.bashrc` to automatically sudo to open files that aren't writable by me:

```
vim() {
    if [ -w "$1" ]; then
        \vim "$1"
    else
        sudo env HOME="$HOME" \vim -u ~/.vimrc "$1"
    fi
}
```

When the file needs sudo, it works fine. When it doesn't, it recursively calls this function and uses 100% of 1 CPU until I C-C.

[From this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39291/run-a-command-that-is-shadowed-by-an-alias) I see there are a few options, all of which I've tried. One actually works:

```
'vim' "$1" #fails
\vim "$1" #fails
command vim "$1" #Works!
```

Why do the other options not work as I would expect them to?

(I know this is a duplicate, but it was very hard to find my answer on SO/SE with the current question titles, so I wanted to post a question with a title that I and others could've found by google searching)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Any character in front of an alias will prevent the alias from triggering:

```
alias ls='ls -la'
ls foo.txt     #will run ls -la foo.txt
\ls foo.txt    #will run ls foo.txt
'ls' foo.txt   #will run ls foo.txt
'ls foo.txt'   #will run ls foo.txt
```

However, that doesn't stop functions, and you need `command` to reference the underlying builtin if you create a function with the same name.

```
ls () {
    echo "not an alias"
}
alias ls='echo "an alias"'

ls foo.txt          #will echo "an alias"
\ls foo.txt         #will echo "not an alias"
'ls' foo.txt        #will echo "not an alias"
command ls foo.txt  #will actually run `ls`
```

---

#### Explanation

The problem is that the first two options can only deal with aliases. They are not special redirecting operators that can sense if you have a function or command with the same name. All they do is put something in front of the alias, as aliases only expand if they are the first part of a pipe or command

```
alias v='sudo vim'
v x.txt
#automatically expands "v" to "sudo vim" and then does the rest of the command
# v x.txt ==> sudo vim x.txt
```

Bash just tries to expand the first word of a command using the list of aliases it knows about (which you can get with `alias`). Aliases don't take arguments, and can only be the first word (space-separated; `vim x.txt` **won't** expand into `sudo vimim x.txt` using the alias above) in a command to expand properly.

However, expansion never happens to things in single quotes: `echo '$USER'` will print out a literal `$USER` and not what the variable stands for. Also, bash expands `\x` to be `x` (mostly). These aren't extra added-in ways specifically to escape an alias, they're just part of how bash expansion was written. Thus, you can use these methods to let an alias shadow a command and still have access to the actual command.

Answer (score 4):

> Why do the other options not work as I would expect them to?

Because there are some details in the way a command line gets executed.

The basic concept is that the first word of a command line is the command that the shell will search and try to execute, in this **order**:

1. The command line is split on metacharacters (mostly):

   > metacharacters
   >   A character that, when unquoted, separates words.  One of the following:
   >   |  & ; ( ) < > space tab newline
2. If the first **unquoted** word match an alias word, it is replaced by the alias definition. To avoid loops, this is executed only **once** if the new first word match an alias being expanded. This makes this work without loops:

   ```
   $ alias ls='ls -la'
   $ ls dir               # will expand to `ls -la dir`
   ```

   Note that: If the last character of the alias value is a blank, then the next command word following the alias is also checked for alias expansion.
3. If the (resulting) first word is an expansion (like a `$var`), it is replaced (and subject to IFS word splitting (and globing) if not quoted):

   ```
   $ var='echo -e '
   $ $var test '\twords'            # will expand to `echo -e test words`
   test    words
   ```
4. The resulting first word after above expansions (after optional variable assignments) will be searched in this order:

   - special builtins (only in POSIX mode)
   - functions
   - builtins
   - hashed commands (read help hash)
   - external commands (searched in `$PATH` dirs)

   The first match found will be executed.

The order may be changed by (for test):

- To bypass just alias, use `\test` or any other kind of expansion.
- To ignore functions and aliases, use `command test`.
- To execute a builtin, use `builtin test`.
- To execute an external application, use an explicit path: `/bin/test`.

So, a function defined as:

```
$ ls(){ ls; }
```

Will be called in an infinite loop. As also an script which calls the same first word. Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
$0 "$@"
```

Will re-execute the same script in a loop until the kernel breaks out (if the kernel in use has a limit of successive calls to scripts).

The order will be shown by running `type -a`:

```
$ test(){ echo test function; }
$ alias test=test
$ type -a
test is aliased to `test'
test is a function
test ()
{
    echo test function
}
test is a shell builtin
test is /usr/bin/test
```

The function (as defined in the question) will only bypass the alias with `\vim` but not the function. To bypass alias and functions, use command. This function should do what you need:

```
vim() {
        if [ -w "$1" ]; then
            command vim "$1"
        else
            sudo HOME="$HOME" bash -c 'command vim "$@"' _ -u ~/.vimrc "$1"
        fi
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the function call the full path to the `vim` binary, you won't get the recursive loop.   Also, using the `-H` option to sudo sets $HOME.

```
vim() {
    if [ -w "$1" ]; then
        command vim "$1"
    else
        sudo env HOME="$HOME" \vim -u ~/.vimrc "$1"
    fi
}
```

Thanks.  I hadn't thought about this, but now I have it in my `.bashrc`, too.

---

**EDITED:** 
updated calling `command vim` and `sudo env` instead of `sudo -h`.  this way there is no loop to stay in.

Comment: `sudo -H` does not work here (I tried it). [It sets `$HOME` equal to the new user's home](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.3/sudo.man.html), not the home of the user calling sudo. [Also, you might like my .vimrc function to display a message if sudo triggered](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/16718/17205)

Comment: I would suggest `command vim` as a more generic (`PATH`-respecting) approach, rather than `/usr/bin/vim`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the tip.  I have added that to the answer.

Comment: @jeremysprofile that is a pretty cool .vimrc function.  thanks for sharing it.