# What does backslash dot mean as a command?

Tags: bash

A software I installed inserted a line in my profile that reads:

```
[ -s "$SOME_FILE" ] && \. "$SOME_FILE"
```

I know dot `.` is synonymous with `source`, so I suspect this is just sourcing the file, but I have never seen `\.` before; does it do something else?

*Edit, regarding DVs:* searching for "backslash dot" leads to questions regarding `./` when calling executable files, and `man source` leads to a manpage where `\.` does not appear. I don't know what else to try, hence the question.

*Edit 2:* see related questions

- [Why start a shell command with a backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15691977/472610)
- [Backslash at the beginning of a command](https://serverfault.com/q/480271/179285)
- [Why do backslashes prevent alias expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6162903/472610)
- [Run a command that is shadowed by an alias](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/39291/45354)

Comment: `[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A backslash outside of quotes means “interpret the next character literally during parsing”. Since `.` is an ordinary character for the parser, `\.` is parsed in the same way as `.`, and invokes the builtin `.` (of which `source` is a synonym in bash).

There is one case where it could make a difference in this context. If a user has defined an alias called `.` earlier in `.profile`, and `.profile` is being read in a shell that expands aliases (which bash only does by default when it's invoked interactively), then `.` would trigger the alias, but `\.` would still trigger the builtin, because the shell doesn't try alias expansion on words that were quoted in any way.

I suspect that `.` was changed to `\.` because a user complained after they'd made an alias for `.`.

Note that `\.` would invoke a function called `.`. Presumably users who write functions are more knowledgeable than users who write aliases and would know that redefining a standard command in `.profile` is a bad idea if you're going to include code from third parties. But if you wanted to bypass both aliases and functions, you could write `command .`. The author of this snippet didn't do this either because they cared about antique shells that didn't have the `command` builtin, or more likely because they weren't aware of it.

By the way, defining *any* alias in `.profile` is a bad idea because `.profile` is a *session* initialization script, not a *shell* initialization script. Aliases for bash belong in `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 13):

The `\.` is a "literal dot", i.e. just a dot.  It will be taken as the standard `.` command (similar to `source` in `bash`).

[The POSIX standard has this to say](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_01) about this (my emphasis)

> **A `<backslash>` that is not quoted shall preserve the literal value of the following character**, with the exception of a `<newline>`. If a `<newline>` follows the `<backslash>`, the shell shall interpret this as line continuation. **The `<backslash>` and `<newline>` shall be removed before splitting the input into tokens**. Since the escaped `<newline>` is removed entirely from the input and is not replaced by any white space, it cannot serve as a token separator.

The dot character *can* be aliased:

```
$ alias .='echo hello'
$ .
hello
```

which means that `\.` would avoid using the aliased version of the `.` command, [because](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03_01),

> After a token has been delimited, but before applying the grammatical rules in Shell Grammar, a resulting word that is identified to be the command name word of a simple command shall be examined to determine **whether it is an unquoted**, valid alias name.

Comment: I was looking for official source about how backslash in a word is interpreted as quoting, and how this prevents alias expansion. Thanks for the reference!

Comment: @Sheljohn See updated answer.