# Why are backslashes included in this shell script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

In my copy of the `conda.sh` script, I see the following lines:

```
if [ -n "${_CE_CONDA}" ] && [ -n "${WINDIR+x}" ]; then
    SYSP=$(\dirname "${CONDA_EXE}")
else
    SYSP=$(\dirname "${CONDA_EXE}")
    SYSP=$(\dirname "${SYSP}")
fi
```

I am curious as to why there is a backslash in front the the `d` in `dirname`. I do not believe it is necessary. This use of backslashes also appears in other places in the source file. Is there a reason for doing this that I am missing?

Comment: Related: [Run a command that is shadowed by an alias](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39291/run-a-command-that-is-shadowed-by-an-alias)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Backslash will suppress alias expansion, ie it executes the original command and makes sure that alias version does not run.  Scripts can unknowingly run with alias expansion when the system has set `shopt -s expand_aliases` (BASH only) or if it is executed using `source`.

```
./conda.sh          # usually no alias expansion (unless `shopt -s expand_aliases` in BASH)
source ./conda.sh   # alias expansion
. ./conda.sh        # alias expansion
```

Some sysadmins like to put backslash in everything as a preventive measure against side-effects of aliases, just in case it was aliased unintentionally somewhere else and the alias gets expanded as explained previously.  For example, if the system has set this `alias dirname='dirname -z'` somewhere and the condition allows the alias to be expanded, then a script that tries to call dirname will unfortunately call `dirname -z` instead, which was not the script intended.

If there's certainty that such alias do not exist, we can remove all the backslash and it should work fine.

Alternatively, one can use `command` instead of backslash version to suppress alias.  Thus, instead of `\dirname`, one can use `command dirname`, which might look more readable.  (For built-in commands like `cd`, one should use `builtin` instead).  I prefer this instead, as it also bypasses function with same name as well as any aliases.

Comment: Also worth noting is `unalias -a`, which removes all aliases.

Comment: @Centimane Yes but make sure to do `\unalias -a` to suppress alias expansion

Comment: Could the sysadmin also have written `/usr/bin/dirname`?

Comment: @RonJohn Yes he could have in this particular case. However, for some programs different distributions put them in different directories. One instance that comes to mind is `/bin/ed` on Ubuntu vs `/usr/bin/ed` on CentOS. Putting in a full path makes the script less portable.

Comment: @doneal24 what about something like `DIRNAME=$(which dirname)`, since `which` doesn't see aliases?

Comment: @RonJohn You could use `which` to figure it out but is this any more convenient or transparent than using `command dirname` or `\dirname`?

Answer (score 20):

If `conda.sh` is a file meant to be sourced, then the backslashes are for bypassing aliases. Bash typically disables alias expansion for script execution, but for sourced files, which may run in interactive shells, that's not the case. So just `dirname` may run an alias named `dirname`, but `\dirname` will skip alias expansion and run a function or command named `dirname`. (Not just backslashes, though, any quoting will do.)

Comment: Or `command dirname`.

Comment: (`\command dirname`, just in case somebody made an alias for `command` as well.) :|

Comment: Why does it bypass aliases? Is this functionality a special case of something, or did it have to be hardcoded into bash (i.e a hack)?

Comment: @extremeaxe5 bash doesn't do alias expansion if (any part of) the word is quoted.

Comment: @extremeaxe5 if you're asking why the feature exists at all, I don't know. It is in [the POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03_01) however: "the command name word [...] shall be examined to determine whether it is an *unquoted*, valid alias name"