# Change the actual terminal command for executing an application (not just an alias)

Tags: terminal, path, alias

I have a directory on my machine, `~/Code`. I have an alias, `code`, that takes me to that directory. I have just installed `VS Code`, which uses the command `code` to open. I would love to keep my old alias the way it is, and open `VS Code` with something like `vs`. Can this be done? I tried aliasing `vs` to `code` and `code` to `cd ~/Code`, but of course this just ended up linking my aliases together so they both do the same thing.

Comment: Related: [Run a command that is shadowed by an alias](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39291/run-a-command-that-is-shadowed-by-an-alias)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can distinguish between both like this:

```
alias vs='command code'
```