# Ubuntu on Windows Terminal Hanging After Creating an Alias for Starship Prompt

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal, alias, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Distro: **Ubuntu-18.04** (running on Windows 10 WSL2)

My terminal for any new Ubuntu instance is completely frozen with the message "Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal"

This happened after editing the .bashrc file on VIM where all I did was add in an alias for some *ls* command. Once I entered `source .bashrc`, the above message showed up. I am unable to ctrl+C or ctrl+z my out of anything and no prompts show up to allow for any command typing.

[image: screenshotOfTerminal_"Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal"]

It's almost certain I made some sort of mistake while editing the .bashrc file but I'm unable to even view that file, let alone edit and execute it. Any way to fix this issue other than reinstalling the whole distro?

Edit 1: I'm able to see the bashrc file through Windows File Explorer. Here is a portion of it:

[image]

The only part that I edited was adding a new alias called starship, so just this part:

`alias starship='vi ~/.config/starship.toml'`

Looks like correct syntax to me, so now I'm even more confused why this issue is happening.

Edit 2: The terminal hanging just stopped after a while and now I'm able to do work on the terminal again. I didn't really do anything to it, just waited. My guess the issue had nothing to do with the alias addition and was something to do with Starship prompt program.

Edit 3: Answer given by **NotTheDr01ds** perfectly solved the issue. And as brought up by **muru**, the alias most definitely caused the issue in the first place, where I overrode the command `eval "$(starship init bash)"` (at the bottom of the bashrc file) as a result of the new alias called *starship*.

Comment: If you've resolved your issue, you should [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) it as well. This closes the question so it doesn't show up as "unresolved" down the line. Advice how to formulate a good answer is [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: "was something to do with Starship prompt program" ... does that mean there's a `starship` command that's used for your prompt, and you created a `starship` alias that overrides that command to run `vi` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to me to be expected behavior.  While your most recent edit says that you regained control over the terminal, my guess is that the error will reappear the next time you start WSL.

Here's what's happening:

- When you install Starship, it tells you to add the following line at the bottom of your `~/.bashrc`:

  ```
  eval "$(starship init bash)"
  ```
- You then *redefined* the `starship` command as an alias in Bash above that with:

  ```
  alias starship='vi ~/.config/starship.toml'
  ```

Result:

The last line in your `~/.bashrc` is interpreted as:

```
eval "$(vi ~/.config/starship.toml init bash)"
```

If you enter that line, you'll see the same error message, and the terminal will hang again.  What's happening is that `vi` is running in a Bash command substitution.  This is a subshell that is *not* interactive, and thus does not have a terminal attached to it.  Standard output (et. al.) does not go to the screen, but instead is captured to be interpreted (`eval`'d) by the shell.

So `vi` is running as soon as you source your `~/.bashrc` (or restart your shell).  Knowing this, you *can* likely recover from it with something like:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>

That's basically trying to get Vim back into a state where it can accept a "quit" command (<kbd>:</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>).  Even though you can't see what's happening, Vim is still processing the keys.

Another way to recover would be to start a new PowerShell terminal, then run:

```
wsl ~ -e bash --noprofile --norc
```

That will start WSL (and Bash) without processing the problematic `~/.bashrc`, allowing you to `ps auxw`, kill the offending `vi` process, and then edit your `~/.bashrc` to fix the problem.

You have (at least) three potential fixes:

- Recommended:  Get rid of the alias entirely.  You'll find that aliases like this aren't that useful, as you won't edit that file all that often anyway.  And there are literally dozens (if not hundreds) of configuration files you'll need to edit when using Linux, so it just doesn't make much sense to set up an alias for each of them.
- If you want to keep the alias, rename it so that it doesn't clash with an existing command `edit_my_prompt` or something like that.
- Or, change the last line (that invokes Starship) to be:

  ```
  eval "$(command starship init bash)"
  ```

  Putting `command` before a command will cause it to ignore the alias and call the actual `starship` command as intended.  Also see [Run a command that is shadowed by an alias](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/39291/432493).