# progress information via pv for directory copy

Tags: osx, directory, cp, progress-information

I need to copy a very large directory (talking in terabytes here) and want to monitor the progress.

I found that `pv` is a nice utility, but how can I use it for copying directories recursively? (`pv src > dst` doesn't work because they are directories)

PS: Running on OS X Mountain Lion, `pv` was installed from Mac Ports

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `rsync --progress [SRC] [DST]`

Do check the `man rsync` page because it has a lot of very useful options. `-a` for archive is a good start, but it depends on your exact requirements.

Copying through a pipe will unnecessarily slow down the copy process, especially if it is files based.

Comment: Why would copying through a pipe slow down the process? The buffering provided by pipes and the multi-tasking associated with pipes is likely to help matters I would say. (and rsync is multi-processes and uses pipes internally IIRC). What's a copy-process that is not file-based?

Comment: Bash is convenient, but not fast. Especially when piping one command to the other.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: Because a pipe's buffer is only 8KB. A program like rsync might want to use a much larger internal buffer.

Comment: Note that `--progress` will only show you the per-file progress of each single file, not the overall process of a potentially larger file copy process of several files / folders.

Answer (score 12):

You could use `tar` or `pax` or `cpio`:

```
mkdir -p dst &&
  (cd src && tar cf - .) | pv -trb | (cd dst && tar xpf -)
```

Comment: Additionally, you may add a `v` to the `tar` command to see the file names.

Comment: So this will zip the source folder before doing the copy, right? My folder is 5 TB in size, so I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it? I really like using pv as it shows a really good progress status, any advice please?

Comment: @Tak, no it doesn't zip anything as there's no compression. `tar cf -` outputs a stream containing the files and their metadata, which is fed through a pipe to pv which feeds it untouched to the other `tar` while printing a progress indication, and the other `tar` extracts the data in that stream. All three commands run concurrently and process data as it comes, there is nothing stored on disk, there is nothing stored in memory other than the pipe buffers and the commands internal buffers which just amounts to a few kilobytes.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for the comment. I've tried it and it's working, the only thing is that the progress bar doesn't show the expected percentage it keeps going from left to right. Any idea why? I used pv with this parameters -petra which usually shows the progress bar where the bar kept getting filled until it finishes. I've upvoted your answer as well.

Comment: @Tak, `pv` has no way to know how much data there is to transfer. If you have an estimate of that amount, you can pass it to it with the `-s` option (GNU `du -sb src` would give you a good approximation if the files are large enough)

Answer (score 2):

Tar.

```
tar -cf - /var/log/ | pv | tar -C . -x
```

Example:

```
# tar -cf - /var/log/ | pv | tar -C . -x
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
58MB 0:00:05 [ 2.2MB/s] [                   <=>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some commands to copy directories with progress information.

---

If there are many small files:

```
cp -av sourcedir targetdir | pv -l -s filecount > logfile
```

This will report progress based on number of files that are copied.

You can redirect to `/dev/null` if you don't need `logfile`.

Use the following command to get `filecount`:

```
find sourcedir | wc -l
```

---

If there are few huge files:

```
tar c sourcedir | pv -s size | tar x -C targetdir
```

This will report progress based on bytes that are copied.

`targetdir` must exist.

Use the following command to get `size`:

```
du -sh sourcedir
```

---

If you want to use rsync:

```
rsync -ai sourcedir/ targetdir/ | pv -l -s filecount > logfile
```

Get `filecount` as shown above.

If you are copying on the same system then `rsync -a` is practically the same as `cp -a` . The advantages of rsync is when you are copying over the network or if you are updating (or comparing) a previous copy.

See here for more details:

[Estimate time or work left to finish for rsync?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188758/estimate-time-or-work-left-to-finish-for-rsync/329603#329603)

[Compare directories but not content of files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59336/compare-directories-but-not-content-of-files/308319#308319)

---

for completeness some more alternatives

https://github.com/Xfennec/progress this tool can report progress even if the process already started.

https://github.com/aioobe/eta this can report progress based on any value obtained from a command. for example `df -h`

Answer (score 1):

I made a progress bar for rsync (in a wrapper):

```
rsyncy -a FROM/ TO
```

It looks like this:

[image: rsyncy]

More info on [GitHub](https://github.com/laktak/rsyncy), install with `pip3 install --user rsyncy`

Answer (score 0):

You could do a `du -b /directory/` on both source and destination while a normal copy command is in progress, and compare the two. This is just as effective and doesn't slow the copy process by pushing it through a pipe.

Answer (score -1):

```
find source-dir -print0 | xargs -0 -I % pv % > dest-dir/%
```

Comment: Please explain tour solutipon, you‘ll want OP to be able to checo it (and learn)