# Compare directories but not content of files

Tags: diff, file-comparison

With

```
diff -r
```

I can do this task, however it takes so long because `diff` checks file's content.

I want something that determine that two files are the same regarding of their size, last modified, etc. But no checking bit by bit the file (for example a video takes sooo long).

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

rsync compares only metadata by default.

```
rsync -n -a -i --delete source/ target/
```

explanation:

- `-n` compare but do not actually copy or delete <-- THIS IS IMPORTANT!!1
- `-a` compare all metadata
- `-i` print one line of information per file
- `--delete` also report files which are in target but not in source

note: it is important to append the directory names with a slash. this is an rsync thing.

also note: rsync is a powerful tool. some explanation above is crudely simplified for the context of this question. especially `-a` is much more complex than just "all metadata".

you can shorten the one letter options like this

```
rsync -nai --delete source/ target/
```

you can provide `-i` twice to also have information printed for files that are identical

```
rsync -naii --delete source/ target/
```

example output:

```
.d..t...... ./            (directory with different timestamp)
>f.st...... modifiedfile  (file with different size and timestamp)
>f+++++++++ newfile       (file in source but not in target)
*deleting   removedfile   (file in target but not in source)
.f          samefile      (file that has same metadata. only with -ii)
```

remember that rsync only compares metadata. that means if the file content changed but metadata is still the same then rsync will report that file is same. this is an unlikely scenario. typically if data changes then metadata will also change. so either trust that when metadata is same then data is same, or you have to compare file data bit by bit.

bonus: for progress information see here: [Estimate time or work left to finish for rsync?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188758/estimate-time-or-work-left-to-finish-for-rsync/329603#329603)

Comment: The slashes in `source/` and `target/` are also both very important! (Without them, you will compare source and target directory names along with the child file names, so all file names will differ.)

Comment: I wish I had read your comment earlier, this is so important! I omitted the slash in source only and then I was wondering why the files in target didn't show up as `*deleting`, but files, which are in source only did show up. The slashes are easy to accidentally forget and then you get a plausible but wrong output.

Comment: I just wanted to mention this in case someone else ran into this -- the command, as it is above, doesn't seem to target dotfiles. From a Mac, comparing files on an AWS FSx share, I needed to specify the '.' for the directory, for it to pick up the dotfiles: `rsync -n -a -i --delete /Volumes/share/AdvantageProxy/Development/bin/. /Volumes/share/AdvantageProxy/Deploy-QA-2020-02-21/bin/.`

Answer (score 7):

I've just discovered `tree`.

```bsh
tree old_dir/ > tree_old
tree new_dir/ > tree_new
vimdiff tree_old tree_new
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `-q` (`--brief`) option with `diff -r` (`diff -qr`).  From the `info` page for GNU `diff`:

> ## 1.6 Summarizing Which Files Differ
>
> When you only want to find out whether files are different, and you
>   don't care what the differences are, you can use the summary output
>   format.  In this format, instead of showing the differences between
>   the files, `diff' simply reports whether files differ.  The`--brief'
>   (`-q') option selects this output format.
>
> This format is especially useful when comparing the contents of two
>   directories.  It is also much faster than doing the normal line by
>   line comparisons, because `diff' can stop analyzing the files as soon
>   as it knows that there are any differences.

This will not compare line by line, but rather the file as a whole, which greatly speeds up the processor (what' you're looking for).

Comment: The problem of - q is that it compares normal and when finds a difference stops (if were normal mode it keeps comparing),  so if huge files are the same it will last a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a quick Python script that will check that the filenames, mtimes, and file sizes are all the same:

```python
import os
import sys

def get_stats(path):
    for pathname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for filename in (os.path.join(pathname, x) for x in filenames):
            stat = os.stat(filename)
            yield filename[len(path):], stat.st_mtime, stat.st_size

left = tuple(get_stats(sys.argv[1]))
right = tuple(get_stats(sys.argv[2]))

print(set(left) ^ set(right))

sys.exit(left != right)
```

Comment: This checks if everything matches, but doesn't print *which files* don't match.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid I edited the source code to fix the problem (will be visible when somebody approves it, sigh)

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to know if files from two file system branch are different (without look inside files) you can do something like this:

```
find /opt/branch1 -type f | sort | xargs -i md5sum {} >/tmp/branch1;
find /opt/branch2 -type f | sort | xargs -i md5sum {} >/tmp/branch2;
diff /tmp/branch1 /tmp/branch2;
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to compare only a structure and some basic info about files, you can try something like this:

```
diff <(cd $DIR1 && ls -laR) <(cd $DIR2 && ls -laR)
```

I didn't test it, so any edits are welcome :)

Comment: This won't work as the directory names themselves will also be in the results.

Comment: what if we will exclude first column with directory names? like <(ls -laR | awk '{$1=""; print}')

Comment: Not all lines are directory names, so that won't work properly.

Comment: Take advantage of the fact that each `<()` has its own environment. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Chris Down's script, this script is a little more "visual". Calling it with two arguments `folder1` and `folder2`, it walks the first folder and for each file searches a corresponding file in the second folder. If it is found, the relative path is printed in green, if they have different modified time or size, it is printed in yellow, and if it is not found then it is printed in red.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
from termcolor import colored

def compare_filestats(file1,file2):
    """
    Compares modified time and size between two files.
    Return:
        -1 if file1 or file2 does not exist
         0 if they exist and compare equal
         1 if they have different modified time, but same size
         2 if they have different size, but same modified time
         3 if they have different size, and different modified time
    """

    if not os.path.exists(file1) or not os.path.exists(file2):
        return -1

    stat1 = os.stat(file1)
    stat2 = os.stat(file2)

    return (stat1.st_mtime != stat2.st_mtime) \
        + 2*(stat1.st_size != stat2.st_size)

def compare_folders(folder1,folder2):
    """
    folder1: serves as reference and will be walked through
    folder2: serves as target and will be querried for each file in folder1

    Prints colored status for each file in folder1:
        missing: file was not found in folder2 
        mtime  : modified time is different
        size   : filesize is different
        ok     : found with same filestats
    """
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(folder1):
        for file1 in ( os.path.join(dirpath, x) for x in filenames ):
            relpath = file1[len(folder1):]
            file2 = os.path.join( folder2, relpath )
            comp = compare_filestats(file1,file2)

            if comp < 0:
                status = colored('[missing]','red')
            elif comp == 1:
                status = colored('[mtime  ]','yellow')
            elif comp >= 2:
                status = colored('[size   ]','yellow')
            else:
                status = colored('[ok     ]','green')

            print status, relpath

if __name__ == '__main__':
    compare_folders(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
```

Note that this is **not** sufficient to decide whether the two folders are the same, you would need to run it both ways to make sure. In practice if you just want to know *whether the folders are the same*, then Chris' script is better. If you want to know *what's missing or different from one folder to another*, then my script will tell you.

NOTE: you will need termcolor installed, `pip install termcolor`.

Answer (score 1):

Save the next code as: `diffm.sh`:

```
# DIFF with Modification date - a .sh (dash; bash; zsh - compatible) 
# "diff utility"-like script that can compare files in two directory 
# trees by path, size and modification date

# Disclaimer:
# By using this program you are assuming full responsibility (and the 
# author of this program shall not be held liable) for any data loss 
# or damage that may result from the use or misuse of this program.


Proc1 () {
    new="$line"
    first_remaining_part="${new%"///////"*}"
    time="${first_remaining_part#*"///////"}"
    first_part="${new%%" ///////"*}"
    #last_part="${new##*"///////"}"

    seconds_since_epoch="${new##*" "}"
    #convert seconds_since_epoch to base 10 (remove 0's padding):
    temp="${seconds_since_epoch#"0"*[1-9]}"
    zeros="${seconds_since_epoch%"$temp"}"
    zeros="${zeros%?}" #Remove last non-0 digit
    seconds_since_epoch="${seconds_since_epoch#"$zeros"}"

    time_zone="${time##*" "}"
    time="${time%"."*}"

    new="$first_part ///// $time $time_zone ///// $seconds_since_epoch"

    printf '%s\n' "$new"
}

Proc2 () {
    cd "$dir1" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null

    count_files=0

    {
        IFS="
"
        set -f
        #FilePath / FileType / FileSize / FileTime / SecondsSinceEpoch
        if [ "$OS" = "Linux" -o "$OS" = "Windows" ]; then
            find . -not -type d -printf '%p ///// <_ ///// %s ///////%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %Tz///////' -exec stat --printf ' %Y\n' {} \; 2>/dev/null|\
            {\
            while read line; do {\
                count_files=$((count_files + 1));\
                PrintJustInTitle "Analyzing file $count_files...";\
                Proc1;\
            }; done;\
            printf "$count_files">$RAMLocation/diffm_count.txt;\
            }
        elif [ "$OS" = "Mac" ]; then
            gfind . -not -type d -printf '%p ///// <_ ///// %s ///////%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %Tz///////' -exec gstat --printf ' %Y\n' {} \; 2>/dev/null|\
            {\
            while read line; do {\
                count_files=$((count_files + 1));\
                PrintJustInTitle "Analyzing file $count_files...";\
                Proc1;\
            }; done;\
            printf "$count_files">$RAMLocation/diffm_count.txt;\
            }
        fi
        unset IFS
        set +f
    }

    cd "$initial_dir"
}

Proc3 () {
    cd "$dir2" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null

    #Get previous line count value from diffm_count.txt:
    read count_files<"$RAMLocation/diffm_count.txt"
    #Validate count_files as a number:
    count_files=$((count_files))

    {
        IFS="
"
        set -f
        #FilePath / FileType / FileSize / FileTime / SecondsSinceEpoch
        if [ "$OS" = "Linux" -o "$OS" = "Windows" ]; then
            find . -not -type d -printf '%p ///// >_ ///// %s ///////%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %Tz///////' -exec stat --printf ' %Y\n' {} \; 2>/dev/null|\
            {\
            while read line; do {\
                count_files=$((count_files + 1));\
                PrintJustInTitle "Analyzing file $count_files...";\
                Proc1;\
            }; done;\
            printf "$count_files">$RAMLocation/diffm_count.txt;\
            }
        elif [ "$OS" = "Mac" ]; then
            gfind . -not -type d -printf '%p ///// >_ ///// %s ///////%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %Tz///////' -exec gstat --printf ' %Y\n' {} \; 2>/dev/null|\
            {\
            while read line; do {\
                count_files=$((count_files + 1));\
                PrintJustInTitle "Analyzing file $count_files...";\
                Proc1;\
            }; done;\
            printf "$count_files">$RAMLocation/diffm_count.txt;\
            }
        fi
        unset IFS
        set +f
    }

    #Get total line count value from diffm_count.txt:
    read count_files<"$RAMLocation/diffm_count.txt"
    #Validate count_files as a number:
    count_files=$((count_files))

    #"." in front of the number is for displaying it as first line after the sort operation:
    printf ".$count_files"

    cd "$initial_dir"
}

GetOS () {
    OS_kernel_name=$(uname -s)

    case "$OS_kernel_name" in
        "Linux")
            eval $1="Linux"
        ;;
        "Darwin")
            eval $1="Mac"
        ;;
        "CYGWIN"*|"MSYS"*|"MINGW"*)
            eval $1="Windows"
        ;;
        "")
            eval $1="unknown"
        ;;
        *)
            eval $1="other"
        ;;
    esac
}

PrintInTitle () {
    printf "\033]0;%s\007" "$1"
}

PrintJustInTitle () {
    PrintInTitle "$1">/dev/tty
}

trap1 () {
    CleanUp
    printf "\nAborted.\n">/dev/tty
}

CleanUp () {
    #Clear the title:
    PrintJustInTitle ""
    #Restore "INTERRUPT" (CTRL-C) and "TERMINAL STOP" (CTRL-Z) signals:
    trap - INT
    trap - TSTP
}

GetSetRAMLocation () {
    GetOS OS
    if [ "$OS" = "Linux" ]; then
        RAMLocation='/dev/shm'
    elif [ "$OS" = "Mac" ]; then
        RAMLocation='/Volumes/RamDiskDIFFM'
        sizeInMB = "1"
        if [ ! -e "/Volumes/RamDiskDIFFM" ]; then
            diskutil partitionDisk $(hdiutil attach -nomount ram://$((2048*sizeInMB))) 1 GPTFormat APFS 'RamDiskDIFFM' '100%'&&{
                printf "">"$RAMLocation/diffm_count.txt"&&{
                    error="false"
                }||{
                    printf '\n%s\n\n' "Error: Could not write to RAM (\"$RAMLocation/diffm_count.txt\"). Write to current directory instead? [ Yes (=continue) / No (=Enter=abort) ]">/dev/tty
                    read answer
                    case "$answer" in
                        "Y"|"y"|"Yes"|"yes")
                            answer="yes"
                        ;;
                        "N"|"n"|"No"|"no")
                            answer="no"
                        ;;
                        "")
                            answer="no"
                        ;;
                        *)
                            answer="no"
                        ;;
                    esac
                    if [ "$answer" = "yes" ]; then
                        RAMLocation="$initial_dir"
                        error="false"
                    elif [ "$answer" = "no" ]; then
                        printf "\nAborted.\n\n">/dev/tty
                        error="true"
                    fi
                }
            }||{
                printf '\n%s\n\n' "ERROR: Could not create RAM Volume!">/dev/tty
                error="true"
            }
        fi
        if [ "$error" = "true" ]; then
            CleanUp
            exit 1
        fi
    elif [ "$OS" = "Windows" ]; then
        #On Windows, the RAMLocation variable is not currently designed to point to a RAM Drive path:
        RAMLocation="$initial_dir"
    elif [ $OS" = "other ]; then
        #On other operating systems, the RAMLocation variable is not currently designed to point to a RAM Drive path:
        RAMLocation="$initial_dir"
    else
        printf '\n%s\n\n' "ERROR: Could not get OS!">/dev/stderr
        CleanUp
        exit 1
    fi
}

DestroyArray () {
    eval array_len=\$\(\($1\_0\)\)

    j=0;
    while [ "$j" -lt "$array_len" ]; do
        j=$((j+1))
        unset $1\_$j
    done
    unset $1\_0
}

DisplayHelp () {
    printf "\n"
    printf "diffm - DIFF with Modification date\n"
    printf "\n"
    printf "    What it does:\n"
    printf "        - compares the files (recursively) in the two provided directory tree paths (<dir_tree1> and <dir_tree2>) by:\n"
    printf "            1. Path\n"
    printf "            2. Size\n"
    printf "            3. Modification date\n"
    printf "    Syntax:\n"
    printf "        <caller_shell> '/path/to/diffm.sh' <dir_tree1> <dir_tree2> [flags]\n"
    printf "        - where:\n"
    printf "            - <caller_shell> can be any of the shells: dash, bash, zsh, or any other shell compatible with the \"dash\" shell syntax\n"
    printf "            - '/path/to/diffm.sh' represents the path of this script\n"
    printf "            - <dir_tree1> and <dir_tree2> represent the directory trees to be compared\n"
    printf "            - [flags] can be:\n"
    printf "                --help or -h\n"
    printf "                    Displays this help information\n"
    printf "    Output:\n"
    printf "        - lines starting with '<' signify files from <dir_tree1>\n"
    printf "        - lines starting with '>' signify files from <dir_tree2>\n"
    printf "    Notes:\n"
    printf "        - only files in the two provided directory tree paths are compared, not also directories\n"
    printf "\n"
}

##################
### MAIN START ###
##################

GetOS OS

if [ "$OS" = "Linux" -o "$OS" = "Windows" ]; then
    error1="false"
    error2="false"
    error3="false"

    { sort --version-sort --help >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; } || { error1="true"; }
    { stat --help >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; } ||  { error2="true"; }
    { find --help >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; } ||  { error3="true"; }
    if [ "$error1" = "true" -o "$error2" = "true" -o "$error3" = "true" ]; then
        {
        printf "\n"
        if [ "$error1" = "true" ]; then printf '%s' "ERROR: Could not run \"sort --version-sort\" (necessary in order for this script to function correctly)!"; fi
        if [ "$error2" = "true" ]; then printf '%s' "ERROR: Could not run \"stat\" (necessary in order for this script to function correctly)"; fi
        if [ "$error3" = "true" ]; then printf '%s' "ERROR: Could not run \"find\" (necessary in order for this script to function correctly)"; fi
        printf "\n"
        }>/dev/stderr
        exit
    else
        sort_command="sort --version-sort"
    fi
elif [ "$OS" = "Mac" ]; then
    error1="false"
    error2="false"
    error3="false"

    { gsort --version-sort --help >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; } || { error1="true"; }
    { gstat --help >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; } ||  { error2="true"; }
    { gfind --help >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; } ||  { error3="true"; }
    if [ "$error1" = "true" -o "$error2" = "true" -o "$error3" = "true" ]; then
        {
        printf "\n"
        if [ "$error1" = "true" ]; then printf '%s' "ERROR: Could not run \"gsort --version-sort\" (necessary in order for this script to function correctly)!"; fi
        if [ "$error2" = "true" ]; then printf '%s' "ERROR: Could not run \"gstat\" (necessary in order for this script to function correctly)"; fi
        if [ "$error3" = "true" ]; then printf '%s' "ERROR: Could not run \"gfind\" (necessary in order for this script to function correctly)"; fi
        printf "\n"
        
        printf "\n"
        printf '%s\n' "You can install them by installing \"homebrew\" and then GNU \"coreutils\":"
        printf '%s\n' "sudo ruby -e \"\$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)\""
        printf '%s\n' "sudo brew install coreutils"
        }>/dev/stderr

        exit
    else
        sort_command="gsort --version-sort"
    fi
elif [ "$OS" = "unknown" ]; then
    printf '\n%s\n\n' "ERROR: Could not get OS!">/dev/stderr
    CleanUp
    exit 1
elif [ "$OS" = "other" ]; then
    printf '\n%s\n\n' "ERROR: OS currently not supported!">/dev/stderr
    CleanUp
    exit 1
fi


#Get the program parameters into the array "params":
params_count=0
for i; do
    params_count=$((params_count+1))
    eval params_$params_count=\"\$i\"
done
params_0=$((params_count))

if [ "$params_0" = "0" ]; then #if no parameters are provided: display help
    DisplayHelp
    CleanUp && exit 0
fi


#Create a flags array. A flag denotes special parameters:
help_flag="0"
i=1;
j=0;
while [ "$i" -le "$((params_0))" ]; do
    eval params_i=\"\$\{params_$i\}\"
    case "${params_i}" in
    "--help" | "-h" )
        help_flag="1"
    ;;
    * )
        j=$((j+1))
        eval selected_params_$j=\"\$params_i\"
    ;;
    esac

    i=$((i+1))
done

selected_params_0=$j
#Rebuild params array:
DestroyArray params
for i in $(seq 1 $selected_params_0); do
    eval params_$i=\"\$\{selected_params_$i\}\"
done
params_0=$selected_params_0

if [ "$help_flag" = "1" ]; then
    DisplayHelp
else
    #Check program arguments:
    if [ "$params_0" -lt "2" ]; then
        printf '\n%s\n' "ERROR: To few program parameters provided (expected two: <dir_tree1> and <dir_tree2>)!">/dev/stderr
        exit 1
    elif [ "$params_0" -gt "2" ]; then
        printf '\n%s\n' "ERROR: To many program parameters provided (expected two: <dir_tree1> and <dir_tree2>)!">/dev/stderr
        exit 1
    else #two program arguments are provided:
        mask1="$params_1"
        mask2="$params_2"
    fi
        
    #If two program arguments are provided (<dir_tree1> and <dir_tree2>) proceed to checking them:

    initial_dir="$PWD" #Store initial dir
    error_encountered="false"

    [ -e "$params_1" -a -d "$params_1" ] && cd "$params_1" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null && {
        dir1="$PWD"
        cd "$initial_dir"
    }||{
        printf '\n%s\n' "ERROR: \"$params_1\" does not exist as a directory or is not accessible!">/dev/stderr
        error_encountered="true"
    }

    printf "\n">/dev/tty

    [ -e "$params_2" -a -d "$params_2" ] && cd "$params_2" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null && {
        dir2="$PWD"
        cd "$initial_dir"
    }||{
        printf '%s\n' "ERROR: \"$params_2\" does not exist as a directory or is not accessible!">/dev/stderr
        error_encountered="true"
    }

    if [ "$error_encountered" = "true" ]; then
        printf "\n">/dev/stderr
        exit
    fi

    GetSetRAMLocation

    #Trap "INTERRUPT" (CTRL-C) and "TERMINAL STOP" (CTRL-Z) signals:
    trap 'trap1' INT
    trap 'trap1' TSTP

    #Proceed to <dir_tree1> and <dir_tree2> compare:
    IFS="
"
    set -f
    unset count_total
    unset previous_line
    unset current_line
    unset previous_case
    skip="0"
    count="0"
    found_previous="false"
    found_previous_last_line_case="false"
    for l in $(\
        {\
            PrintJustInTitle "Loading file data, please wait...";\
            Proc2;\
            Proc3;\
            PrintJustInTitle "Sorting results, please wait...";\
        }|eval $sort_command;
    ); do
        if [ -z "$count_total" ]; then
            # #? is for removing the "." in front of the number:
            count_total=$((${l#?}))
        else
            count=$((count + 1))
            PrintJustInTitle "Analyzing file $count of $count_total"
            if [ -z "$current_line" ]; then
                #FilePath / FileType / FileSize / FileTime / SecondsSinceEpoch

                #Get previous FileType = if from <dir_tree1> or <dir_tree2>:
                previous_line_type="${l#*"///// "}"
                #extract first character from $previous_line_type ("<" or ">"):
                previous_line_type_temp="${previous_line_type#?}"
                previous_line_type="${previous_line_type%"$previous_line_type_temp"}"

                #Remove FileType from line:
                previous_line="$l"
                previous_line_file_path="${l%%" /////"*}"
                previous_line_last_part="${previous_line#*"///// ""$previous_line_type""_ ///// "}"
                previous_line="$previous_line_file_path /////$previous_line_last_part"

                previous_line_file_size="${previous_line_last_part%%" /////"*}"
                previous_line_seconds_since_epoch="${l##*" "}"

                previous_line_file_time="${previous_line#*"///// "}"
                previous_line_file_time="${previous_line_file_time%%" /////"*}"

                current_line="$previous_line"
                current_line_file_path="$previous_line_file_path"
                current_line_file_size="$previous_line_file_size"
                current_line_seconds_since_epoch="$previous_line_seconds_since_epoch"

                current_line_type="$previous_line_type"

                current_line_file_time="$previous_line_file_time"
            else
                #FilePath / FileType / FileSize / FileTime / SecondsSinceEpoch

                previous_line="$current_line"
                previous_line_file_path="$current_line_file_path"
                previous_line_file_size="$current_line_file_size"
                previous_line_seconds_since_epoch="$current_line_seconds_since_epoch"

                previous_line_type="$current_line_type"

                previous_line_file_time="$current_line_file_time"

                #Get current FileType = if from <dir_tree1> or <dir_tree2>:
                current_line_type="${l#*"///// "}"
                #extract first character from $current_line_type ("<" or ">"):
                current_line_type_temp="${current_line_type#?}"
                current_line_type="${current_line_type%"$current_line_type_temp"}"

                #Remove FileType from line:
                current_line="$l"
                current_line_file_path="${l%%" /////"*}"
                current_line_last_part="${current_line#*"///// ""$current_line_type""_ ///// "}"
                current_line="$current_line_file_path /////$current_line_last_part"

                current_line_file_size="${current_line_last_part%%" /////"*}"
                current_line_seconds_since_epoch="${l##*" "}"

                current_line_file_time="${current_line#*"///// "}"
                current_line_file_time="${current_line_file_time%%" /////"*}"

                if [ ! "$skip" = "$count"  ]; then
                    if [ "$found_previous" = "false" ]; then
                        seconds_difference=$(($current_line_seconds_since_epoch - $previous_line_seconds_since_epoch))
                        if [ \
                            \( "$current_line" = "$previous_line" \) -o \
                            \( \
                                \( "$current_line_file_path" = "$previous_line_file_path" \) -a \
                                \( "$current_line_file_size" = "$previous_line_file_size" \) -a \
                                \( "$seconds_difference" = "1" -o "$seconds_difference" = "-1" \) \
                            \) \
                        ]; then
                            found_previous="true"
                            found_previous_last_line_case="false"
                            skip=$((count+1))
                        else
                            printf '%s\n' "$previous_line_type $previous_line_file_path - ""Size: ""$previous_line_file_size"" Bytes"" - ""Modified Date: ""$previous_line_file_time"
                            found_previous="false"
                            found_previous_last_line_case="true"
                        fi
                    else
                        printf '%s\n' "$previous_line_type $previous_line_file_path - ""Size: ""$previous_line_file_size"" Bytes"" - ""Modified Date: ""$previous_line_file_time"
                        found_previous="false"
                        found_previous_last_line_case="true"
                    fi
                else
                    found_previous="false"
                    found_previous_last_line_case="true"
                fi
            fi
        fi
    done
    #Treat last case sepparatelly:
    if [ "$found_previous_last_line_case" = "true" ]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$current_line_type $current_line_file_path - ""Size: ""$current_line_file_size"" Bytes"" - ""Modified Date: ""$current_line_file_time"
    fi

    unset IFS
    set +f
fi

CleanUp
```

- How to use it:

  Syntax: `<caller_shell> '/path/to/diffm.sh' <dir_tree1> <dir_tree2>`

  where: `<caller_shell>` can be any of the shells: `dash`, `bash`, `zsh`, or any other shell compatible with the `dash` shell syntax.
- What it does: Compares the files (recursively) in the two provided directory tree paths (`<dir_tree1>` and `<dir_tree2>`) by:

  1. Path
  2. Size
  3. Modification Date

**Notes**:

- This script compares only the files, not also the directories in `<dir_tree1>` and `<dir_tree2>`.
- To find out how to use the script, you can call it with the `--help` flag.

Comment: Note: an “improved” version of this script [has been posted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/197677/80216#638761). I have written some comments there, many of which are applicable to this original.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open for a GUI-based solution, [`meld`](https://meldmerge.org/help/folder-mode.html) can also perform directory comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Midnight commander (mc in Debian linux) is a two-pane command-line file manager with a Compare Directories function (C-x d; that is, holding the control key, press x, release, then press d). It has three choices: Quick, Size only, and Thorough. Quick or Size only may be helpful to you. It then highlights the files that are different in both panes, so you can do something to one or both sets.

I use the rsync method given above when I have a lot of files and a clear source and destination directory. But I often find I have two directories that each have new files to synchronize and I end up using mc frequently.