# Compare massive directories with progress report

Tags: rsync, diff, progress-information

I just rsync-ed 2,000,000 files (3TB) from one RAID to another.

I want to make sure my data is intact.

`rsync -c` takes a really long time.

`diff` doesn't show me what it's doing.

Is there an alternative that's (a) faster, and (b) will show me progress while it's comparing?

(I'm on Mac, and `brew search diff` gives me `apgdiff       colordiff   diffstat    diffutils   fmdiff      libxdiff    open-vcdiff podiff      rfcdiff     vbindiff
bsdiff      diffpdf     diffuse     dwdiff      kdiff3      ndiff       perceptualdiff  rdiff-backup    tkdiff      wdiff`
 ... would one of these do the job?)

Comment: Duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/708001/alternative-to-diff-with-progress-for-massive-directory-compare

Comment: I'm also confused as to why `rsync` copied the data at around 150MB/s, yet `diff` compares at only 60MB/s ... ?

Comment: The copy using `rsync` is faster b/c `rsync` by default does not use checksums to compare files, it looks at size and date info. When you use `rsync -c` all the files need to have their checksums' calculated which is a burdensome task, hence why it's not the default.

Comment: Yes, but diff doesn't copy ... it just reads both files; while rsync, to copy, must read each byte, then write it. This was an rsync from scratch, so it was copying every file.

Answer (score 12):

Here is `diff` with progress report based on file count:

```
diff -rqs dir1 dir2 | pv -l -s filecount > logfile
```

You will need `pv` (pipe viewer): http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml

To get file count use the following command:

```
find dir1 -type f | wc -l
```

The above commands will report progress based on file count. This works best if there are many smallish files. If your files are huge then you will not have much fun with this. It will still be better than nothing because you still see progress between files. But you will not see how far along the current file it is.

Sadly I do not know of an easy way to report progress based on bytes compared.

Explanation of `diff` options:

- `diff -r` compare not just the files in the given directories but also the files in the subdirectories and subsubdirectories and so forth.
- `diff -q` if there is difference then print only the filenames instead of the actual differences in the files.
- `diff -s` also print filenames of files that do not differ. this is important for the progress information using `pv`.

And `pv` options:

- `pv -l` consider progress based on line count (instead of byte count).
- `pv -s count` estimate time to complete based on `count`.

The redirect to `logfile` is for pretty output. Otherwise output from `diff` will mix with status line from `pv`.

You can omit `-s count`. Then you won't have estimate to finish. Only progress so far.

---

To filter the logfile for files that are different:

```
grep -v "^Files .* identical$" logfile
```

This variation will print files that are different in real time while also logging everything in `logfile`:

```
diff -rqs dir1 dir2 | pv -l -s filecount | 
    tee logfile | grep -v "^Files .* identical$"
```

Alternatively you can log only files that are different:

```
diff -rqs dir1 dir2 | pv -l -s filecount | 
    grep -v "^Files .* identical$" > logfile
```

---

If you can find your peace just comparing the metadata (and not the actual content of the files) then you can use rsync. This will be considerably faster.

For more details:

- [Compare directories but not content of files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59336/compare-directories-but-not-content-of-files/308319#308319)
- [Estimate time or work left to finish for rsync?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188758/estimate-time-or-work-left-to-finish-for-rsync/329603#329603)

Comment: This should be the answer as it actually shows the progress. You may consider adding --speed-large-files for completeness.

Answer (score 7):

edit for correction & option clarity - I forgot '--brief'

```
diff -rs --brief "$dir1" "$dir2" 

-r, --recursive              recursively compare any subdirectories found
-s, --report-identical-files report when two files are the same
-q, --brief                  report only when files differ
--speed-large-files      assume large files and many scattered small changes
```

and add other options to taste, depending on what you are comparing:

```
-i, --ignore-case            ignore case differences in file contents
-b, --ignore-space-change    ignore changes in the amount of white space
-B, --ignore-blank-lines     ignore changes whose lines are all blank
--strip-trailing-cr      strip trailing carriage return on input
--ignore-file-name-case  ignore case when comparing file names
```

diff -rs will read every byte of the original and copy,
and report files that are the same.

The diff output format is defined by POSIX, so it is pretty
portable.  You may want to add something like:

| tee diff-out.1 | grep -v -Ee 'Files .* and .* are identical'

You could use chksums or hashes, but then you have to keep them
sync'd with the file trees, so you would be back to reading every byte
of every file anyway.

EDIT - too long to be a comment, in response to:

> files over 10GB are not verifying

You may want to try this diff option: --speed-large-files

It is possible that the diff you are using is not coping well with
very large files (bigger than system memory, for instance), and is
thus reporting differences between files that are actually the same.

I had thought there was a -h option or a 'bdiff' that did better on
large files, but I cannot find one in Fedora.  I believe that the
--speed-large-files options is a successor to a '-h' "half-hearted
compare" option.

A different approach would be to repeat the rsync command you used,
with '-vin' (verbose, itemize, no_run).  This would report any
differences that rsync finds - and there should not be any.

To move some files, you're looking at a script something like:

```
if [ cmp -s "$dir1/$path" "$dir2/$path" ] ; then 
target="$dir2/verified/$path"
mkdir -p $(basename "$target")
mv  "$dir2/$path" "$target"
fi
```

but I don't recommend doing that.  The underlying question is "how
can I be sure that rsync copied a file hierarchy correctly?"
and if you can demonstrate to yourself that rsync is working
well, with diff or some other tool, then you can just rely
on rsync, rather than working around it.

rsync -vin will compare based on whatever other options you give it.
I thought it defaulted to checksum, but you are right,
-c or --checksum is required for that.

The diff utility is really intended for files of lines of text,
but it should report 'identical' under -s for binary files.

The --brief should suppress any file content output - my apologies
for overlooking it earlier - it was semi-buried in an ugly script.

Comment: Is there a way to get it to `mv` every file it finds to a "verified" folder at the root of the drive, preserving the full path? E.g., if `/disk1/a/b/c/file1` is identical to `/disk2/a/b/c/file1`, then move it to `/disk1/verified/a/b/c/file1`. Then I could end up with only the badly copied files. (So far LOTS of files over 10GB are not verifying, which is scary.)

Comment: You may want to try this option: --speed-large-files

Comment: What does that do exactly?

Comment: If I run `rsync -vin` -- does that do a byte-by-byte or checksum comparison? I thought rsync only compared size/date unless you add `-c`. And from what I've read the `speed large files` seems to only make a difference with non-binary files ... or am I wrong?

Comment: `diff` gives me results in the form of `"Files __ and ___ differ"` ... and I'm running that through `sed -e "s/Files /cp -afv /" -e "s/ and / /" -e "s/ differ$//"` to try and generate a script for re-copying the bad files. But diff's output is unquoted, so it doesn't work. Can I get it to give me quoted paths?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using some sort of hash application to check data integrity. I know that many duplicate file finding utilities use hashes to identify duplicate/non-duplicates. Seems to me that this is an investigation that might be worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rdiff-backup](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/) for that. Install it on both servers and it will do smart comparisons of checksums and sync what is not yet there.