# Compare two URL lists and print newly added URLs to a new file

Tags: bash, command-line, scripting, diff

I am initially producing two files which contain lists of URLs—I will refer to them as `old` and `new`. I would like to compare the two files and if there are any URLs in the `new` file which are not in the `old` file, I would like these to be displayed in an `extra_urls` file.

Now, I've read some stuff about using the `diff` command but from what I can tell, this also analyses the order of the information. I don't want the order to have any effect on the output. I just want the extra URL's in `new` printed to the `extra_urls` file, no matter what order they are placed in either of the other two files.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [`comm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) command to compare two files, and selectively show lines unique to one or the other, or the lines in common. It requires the inputs to be sorted, but you can sort them on the fly, by using process substitution.

```
comm -13 <(sort old.txt) <(sort new.txt)
```

If you're using a version of `bash` that doesn't support process substitution, it can be emulated using named pipes. An example is shown in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution).

Comment: Concise but effective- exactly what was needed, excellent bit of code for what I required.

Comment: Hmm, but if the input is sorted, then `diff` will do the same thing, right?

Comment: `diff` will show all the differences. `comm` allows you to select whether you want to see the lines from file 1, file 2, or the ones they have in common.

Comment: Hi Barmar, not sure you will check this but just incase, i've moved this script onto my Synology Nas to run from there. Since running my script from the Synology I'm now getting the syntax error:  line 60: syntax error: unexpected "("

Comment: What version of `bash` is it running? It may not support process substitution.

Comment: On my synology I have to use use #!/bin/sh at the top of my scripts rather than bash, if that helps?

Comment: I added a link to Wikipedia, which shows how to emulate process substitution with named pipes. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for that mate, I will check when I get home, literally about to get kicked out of the office, will let you know, thanks

Comment: Yes thanks worked Barmar, thanks for your help yet again :)

Answer (score 6):

I would just use `grep`:

```
grep -vFf old new > extra_urls
```

#### Explanation

- `-f` : tells `grep` to read its search patterns from a file. In this case, `old`.
- `-v` : tells grep to invert the match, to only print non-matching lines.
- `-F` : tells grep to interpret its search patterns as strings, not regular expressions. That way, the `.` of the URL will be matched literally.

Combined, these make `grep` print any lines in `new` that were not in `old`. The order of the URLs in the file is irrelevant.

Comment: Hi terdon, Thanks for your input. I've just tested this and it produced a blank "extra urls"_file despite there being new urls in the "new" file.

Comment: @bms9nmh hmm, that's odd. Please [edit] your question to give an example of your input files. You might also want to come into the site's [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux) where we can discuss this further.

Comment: You'll want to add `-F` for plain text patterns

Answer (score 1):

Since order is important to you, use `awk`

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {old[$1]=1; next}
    !($1 in old)
' old new > extra
```

Comment: Hi glen, just to clarify, order isn't important. The url's order isn't an issue, just the difference between the two files i.e. the additional url's. I don't want the difference in order to effect the output in any way.

Comment: @bms9nmh: you could just change `> extra` to `| sort > extra`. or `| sort -u > extra` if you only want a new url to appear in the output once, regardless how many times it's in the input. The input order is liable to affect the output order unless you do extra work somewhere along the way to prevent it.

Comment: @steve, meh, `comm` is the best answer for this question, although `grep -Fvf` is good too

Answer (score 0):

I have an application called meld. It allows viewing the two (or three) files, side by sides, shows the differences and allows for selective copying from one to the other or deleting characters.

Meld can be installed from a terminal with

```
sudo apt-get install meld
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more general solution, that can find and compare URL's in text files containing not just URL's:

```
#!/bin/sh

# diffl.sh

# DIFF with Links - a "diff utility"-like .sh script 
# (dash, bash, zsh compatible) that can find missing 
# web links in one file compared to a group of files

# Please note that: for simplicity, in this script, only 
# URLs containing "://" are taken into consideration, 
# although there can be URLs that do not contain it 
# (such as mailto:user@site.com)

GetOS () {
    
    OS_kernel_name=$(uname -s)
    
    case "$OS_kernel_name" in
        "Linux")
            eval $1="Linux"
        ;;
        "Darwin")
            eval $1="Mac"
        ;;
        "CYGWIN"*|"MSYS"*|"MINGW"*)
            eval $1="Windows"
        ;;
        "")
            eval $1="unknown"
        ;;
        *)
            eval $1="other"
        ;;
    esac
    
}

DetectShell () {
    eval $1=\"\";
    if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
        eval $1=\"bash\";
    elif [ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ]; then
        eval $1=\"zsh\";
    elif [ "$PS1" = '$ ' ]; then
        eval $1=\"dash\";
    else
        eval $1=\"undetermined\";
    fi
}

PrintInTitle () {
    printf "\033]0;%s\007" "$1"
}

PrintJustInTitle () {
    PrintInTitle "$1">/dev/tty
}

trap1 () {
    CleanUp
    printf "\nAborted.\n">/dev/tty
}

CleanUp () {
    
    #Restore "INTERRUPT" (CTRL-C) and "TERMINAL STOP" (CTRL-Z) signals:
    trap - INT
    trap - TSTP
    
    #Clear the title:
    PrintJustInTitle ""
    
    #Restore initial IFS:
    #IFS=$old_IFS
    unset IFS
}

DisplayHelp () {
    printf "\n"
    printf "diffl - DIFF by URL web Links\n"
    printf "\n"
    printf "    What it does:\n"
    printf "        - compares the URL web links in the two provided files (<file1> and <file2>) and shows the missing web links that are found in one but not in the other\n"
    printf "    Syntax:\n"
    printf "        <caller_shell> '/path/to/diffl.sh' <file1> <file2> ... <fileN> [flags]\n"
    printf "        - where:\n"
    printf "            - <caller_shell> can be any of the shells: dash, bash, zsh, or any other shell compatible with the \"dash\" shell syntax\n"
    printf "            - '/path/to/diffl.sh' represents the path of this script\n"
    printf "            - <file1> and <file2> represent the directory trees to be compared\n"
    printf "                       - if more than two files are provided as parameters (<file1>, <file2>, ..., <fileN>): the web links in <file1> are compared with all the web links in <file2>, ... <fileN>\n"
    printf "            - [flags] can be:\n"
    printf "                --help or -h\n"
    printf "                    Displays this help information\n"
    printf "    Output:\n"
    printf "        - lines starting with '<' signify web links from <file1>\n"
    printf "        - lines starting with '>' signify web links from <file2>, ..., <fileN>\n"
    printf "    Notes:\n"
    printf "               - for simplicity, in this script, only URLs containing \"://\" are taken into consideration, although there can be URLs that do not contain it (such as mailto:user@site.com)\n"
    printf "\n"
}

GetOS OS

#################################################################################
##    Uncomment the next line if your OS is not Linux or Mac (and eventually   ##
##    modify the commands used (sed, sort, uniq) according to your system):    ##
#################################################################################
#OS="userdefined"

DetectShell current_shell

if [ "$current_shell" = "undetermined" ]; then
    printf "\nWarning: This script was designed to work with dash, bash and zsh shells.\n\n">/dev/tty
fi

#Get the program parameters into the array "params":
params_count=0
for i; do
    params_count=$((params_count+1))
    eval params_$params_count=\"\$i\"
done
params_0=$((params_count))

if [ "$params_0" = "0" ]; then #if no parameters are provided: display help
    DisplayHelp
    CleanUp && exit 0
fi


#Create a flags array. A flag denotes special parameters:
help_flag="0"
i=1;
j=0;
while [ "$i" -le "$((params_0))" ]; do
    eval params_i=\"\$\{params_$i\}\"
    case "${params_i}" in
    "--help" | "-h" )
        help_flag="1"
    ;;
    * )
        j=$((j+1))
        eval selected_params_$j=\"\$params_i\"
    ;;
    esac
    
    i=$((i+1))
done
selected_params_0=$j

#Rebuild params array:
for i in $(seq 1 $selected_params_0); do
    eval params_$i=\"\$\{selected_params_$i\}\"
done
params_0=$selected_params_0

if [ "$help_flag" = "1" ]; then
    DisplayHelp
else #Run program:
    
    NL=$(printf '%s' "\n\n"); #final NewLine is deleted
    #or use:
    #NL=$'\n'
    
    error1="false"
    error2="false"
    error3="false"
    { sed --help >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; } || { error1="true"; }
    { sort --help >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; } || { error2="true"; }
    { uniq --help >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; } || { error3="true"; }
    if [ "$error1" = "true" -o "$error2" = "true" -o "$error3" = "true" ]; then
        {
            printf "\n"
            if [ "$error1" = "true" ]; then printf '%s' "ERROR: Could not run \"sed\" (necessary in order for this script to function correctly)!"; fi
            if [ "$error2" = "true" ]; then printf '%s' "ERROR: Could not run \"sort\" (necessary in order for this script to function correctly)"; fi
            if [ "$error3" = "true" ]; then printf '%s' "ERROR: Could not run \"uniq\" (necessary in order for this script to function correctly)"; fi
            printf "\n"
        }>/dev/stderr
        exit
    fi
    
    if [ "$OS" = "Linux" -o "$OS" = "Mac" -o "$OS" = "userdefined" ]; then
        #   command1: sed -E 's/([a-zA-Z]*\:\/\/)/\\${NL}\1/g'
        sed_command1='sed -E '"'"'s/([a-zA-Z]*\:\/\/)/'"\\${NL}"'\1/g'"'";
        #   command2: sed -n 's/\(\(.*\([^a-zA-Z+]\)\|\([a-zA-Z]\)\)\)\(\([a-zA-Z]\)*\:\/\/\)\([^ \t]*\).*/\4\5\7/p'
        sed_command2='sed -n '"'"'s/\(\(.*\([^a-zA-Z+]\)\|\([a-zA-Z]\)\)\)\(\([a-zA-Z]\)*\:\/\/\)\([^ \t]*\).*/\4\5\7/p'"'"
        #   command3: sed -E 's/(.) [0-9]* (.*)/\1 \2/g'
        sed_command3='sed -E '"'"'s/(.) [0-9]* (.*)/\1 \2/g'"'";
        #   command4: sed -E 's/^1/>/g;s/^0/</g'
        sed_command4='sed -E '"'"'s/^1/>/g;s/^0/</g'"'"
    else
        printf '\n%s\n\n' "Error: Unsupported OS!">/dev/stderr
        exit 1
    fi
    
    #Get the program parameters into the array "files":
    count=0
    for i; do
        count=$((count+1))
        eval files_$count=\"\$i\"
    done
    files_0=$((count))
    
    error="false"
    if [ "$files_0" -lt "2" ]; then
        printf '\n%s\n' "ERROR: Please provide at least two parameters!">/dev/stderr
        error="true"
    fi
    
    if [ "$error" = "true" ]; then
        printf "\n"
        exit 1
    fi
    
    error="false"
    for i in $(seq 1 $files_0); do
        eval current_file=\"\$files_$i\"
        if [ ! \( -e "$current_file" -a -f "$current_file" \) ]; then
            printf '\n%s\n' "ERROR: File \"$current_file\" does not exist or is not a regular file!">/dev/stderr
            error="true"
        fi
    done
    
    if [ "$error" = "true" ]; then
        printf "\n"
        exit 1
    fi
    
    #Proceed to finding and comparing links:
    
    #Trap "INTERRUPT" (CTRL-C) and "TERMINAL STOP" (CTRL-Z) signals:
    trap 'trap1' INT
    trap 'trap1' TSTP
    
    old_IFS="$IFS" #Store initial IFS value
    IFS="
    "
    
    {
        PrintJustInTitle "Searching for links [1]..."
        mask="00000000000000000000"
        {
            count=0
            for link in $(\
                cat "$files_1" |\
                eval $sed_command1 |\
                eval $sed_command2\
            ); do
                count_prev=$count
                count=$((count+1))
                if [ "${#count_prev}" -lt "${#count}" ]; then
                    mask="${mask%?}"
                fi
                number="$mask$count"
                printf '%s\n' "0 $number $link"
                PrintJustInTitle "Links found [1]: $((count))..."
            done;
            
            PrintJustInTitle "Sorting results [1]..."
        }|sort -u -k 3
        
        PrintJustInTitle "Searching for links [2]..."
        mask="00000000000000000000"
        {
            count=0
            for i in $(seq 2 $files_0); do
                eval current_file=\"\$files_$i\"
                for link in $(\
                    cat "$current_file" |\
                    eval $sed_command1 |\
                    eval $sed_command2\
                ); do
                    count_prev=$count
                    count=$((count+1))
                    if [ "${#count_prev}" -lt "${#count}" ]; then
                        mask="${mask%?}"
                    fi
                    number="$mask$count"
                    printf '%s\n' "1 $number $link"
                    PrintJustInTitle "Links found [2]: $((count))..."
                done
            done
            
            PrintJustInTitle "Sorting results [2]..."
        }|sort -u -k 3
        
        PrintJustInTitle "Searching for unique links [3]..."
    }|{\
        sort -k 3|uniq -u -f 2|sort|eval $sed_command3|eval $sed_command4
        
        PrintJustInTitle "Done";
    }
    
    CleanUp
fi
```

- Syntax:

  - `<caller_shell> '/path/to/diffl.sh' <file1> <file2> ... <fileN>`
- What it does:

  - this will show the URL web links that `<file1>` and the group of files `<file2>, ..., <fileN>` don't have in common
- Notes:

  - for simplicity, in this script, only URLs containing "`://`" are taken into consideration

Comment: (1) This appears to be similar enough to [your other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/197677/80216#638761) that many of my comments there probably apply here, as well.  (2) When you post an answer that’s derived [from somebody else’s work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/59336/80216#621962), you should say so.

Comment: This script compares only the web links inside files, whereas the other answer compares: date modified, size, path of files... these are different things (and by the way, I am the author of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59336/compare-directories-but-not-content-of-files#621962 )