# How to copy directory and ignore errors

Tags: cp, android

I have a root Linux shell open on my Android device, and while using `cp` to copy a directory, I get an error. I think I know where the error is coming from, so that is not my question.

I want to find a command that will allow me to copy everything within this directory that it can, and not just quit upon encountering an error. This is an example of what happens right now:

```
root@flo:/ # cp -r -v /d/* /sdcard/test/
cp '/d/TRRS'
cp: xread: Invalid argument
1|root@flo:/ #
```

How should I go about this?

Comment: What does `ls -l /d/TRRS` say?

Comment: You may think that error is secondary but `cp -r` is actually meant to do what you're asking.  It does accept a force option (`-f`) but I don't think it would overcome a fatal error like you're getting.

Comment: @Kusalananda `ls -l /d/TRRS` gives: `-r--r--r-- root     root            0 1969-12-31 19:00 TRRS`

Comment: What do you get from `ls -la /d/.`?

Comment: @JuliePelletier [Here's](http://pastebin.com/cCiCnWq8) what I get from `ls -la /d/.`. And just to reiterate, I'm pretty sure I know why it is failing, but I just need a command that can recover from this type of error.

Comment: The solution is to use a more appropriate tool such as `rsync`.  It would also be possible to do a shell script that first retrieves the file listing, creates the directories, and then just runs `cp` on each filename.  You would of course ignore the return code from `cp` and just let it go through.

Comment: `http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/335663/167583` is most relevant.  Simply note you **don't** need the `--remove-source-files` option.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where I needed to copy files from one directory to another and *continue on errors*. The idea was to copy as much as possible with the help of an *operating system* (in my case *Debian*) tool and then handle possible errors manually.

I used the [hint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/335663/173642) [Julie Pelletier](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/167583/) provided in her [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335657/how-to-copy-directory-and-ignore-errors#comment591647_335657) to *[use `rsync`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335657/how-to-copy-directory-and-ignore-errors#comment591644_335657)*. Also I used [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/308319/173642) as template as I wanted to be able to analyze the copy operations which fail.

In summary the solution for your case could be

```
rsync --archive --itemize-changes --delete /d/ /sdcard/test/
```

Explanation: `rsync` copies the contents of your source path (`/d/`) to your target path (`/sdcard/test/`). In case the contents already exist in your target directory only the differences will be written (delta-transfer). This allows to abort and continue the process at any time. Failures will be reported *without stopping* the overall copy operation. `rsync` per default only performs a "quick check" using file size and last modified time. More criteria can be set (see below).

- `--archive` specifies a set of file and directory attributes to be checked for differences
- `--itemize-changes` instructs to print a summary for each file. This is very helpful to understand why a file is considered to be different by `rsync`. This helped me to understand failures of the copy operation. The message is rather cryptic, check the man page to understand it better.
- `--delete` specifies to delete files at the target location which do not exists in your source location.

In my specific case I used a modified set of comparison criteria as I copied from one file system to another. Maybe this is helpful in your case as well:

```
rsync --recursive --links --safe-links --times --group --owner --devices --specials --delete --human-readable --stats --verbose --itemize-changes --progress --modify-window=3 source/ target/
```

The most notable changes are:

- `--safe-links` in order to copy only symbolic links within the copied tree
- No `--perms` (was implied by `--archive`) as permissions were not correctly set on the target filesystem
- `--modify-window=NUM` sets a tolerance for the last modification time as those were not correctly set on the target filesystem