# sort file of unix pathnames from two drives

Tags: filenames, sort

I have a file containing pathnames from two directories. I want to sort them by filename disregarding parent directories.

Text is as so:

```
/mnt/samsung/a/b/c
/mnt/samsung/d/e/f
...
/mnt/wd/a/b/c
/mnt/wd/d/e/f
```

I want to sort as

```
/mnt/samsung/a/b/c
/mnt/wd/a/b/c
/mnt/samsung/d/e/f
/mnt/wd/d/e/f
```

I'm trying with this :

```
 sort -t / -k3
```

And it's not working.

I've tried also :

```
  sort -t "/" -k3 
  sort -t "/" -k2 
  sort -t / -k2
```

None of them working.

What will give what I want?

Comment: do you mean you want to sort on 3rd sub path ? or whatever subpaths that has only one char ?

Comment: The leading `/` means that `a` is the *4th* field, not the 3rd

Comment: We **need** a bigger example. Can you add /mnt/wd/z/d to the input and output lists? This will give us some indication about filenames with differing number of components. Adding /mnt/wd/z/a/d and /mnt/wd/z/e/d as well would help us see what you mean by parent directories.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sort -t '/' -k 6 file
/mnt/samsung/a/b/c
/mnt/wd/a/b/c
/mnt/samsung/d/e/f
/mnt/wd/d/e/f
```

For the given paths, the filename at the end of the path is the 6th `/`-delimited field on each line (the first field is zero-length).

Using `--debug` with GNU `sort`, it would output

```
$ sort --debug -t '/' -k 6 file
sort: text ordering performed using simple byte comparison
/mnt/samsung/a/b/c
                 _
__________________
/mnt/wd/a/b/c
            _
_____________
/mnt/samsung/d/e/f
                 _
__________________
/mnt/wd/d/e/f
            _
_____________
```

... showing that it is using the final path component as the sorting key.

Also possibly related (depending on what the *actual* task is):

- [Compare directories but not content of files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59336/compare-directories-but-not-content-of-files)