# How to find missing directories between two disk structures?

Tags: directory

How to find missing directories between two disk structures?

- Lets say Disk A has dir `A/`, `B/`, `C/`, `D/`. (newer copy)
- Lets say Disk B has dir `A/`, `B/`, `D/`, `E/`. (older copy)

I want to find which directories are missing from newer copy in compared to the older copy.

Results: "Dir E".

How I can do this? I dont want any report on files.

This can create only the missing directories from a specific target:

```
find -type d -exec mkdir -p "/mnt/pics/Albums/{}" \;
```

UPDATE:
The suggested article in my question was about content and not folders.
Also, it was not presented a clear solution as the answer of "diff -rq path1 path2".

Comment: perhaps you can try with `rsync` if you use --dry-run option, it will create a list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare directories but not content of files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59336/compare-directories-but-not-content-of-files)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`diff` allows comparing directory contents. Use `-r` for recursively traversing subdirectories and `-q` for reporting differences only:

```
diff -rq /path/to/dir1 /path/to/dir2
```

E.g.:

```
$mkdir A B
$touch A/1 A/2 A/3 B/1 B/3 B/4
$diff -rq A B
Only in A: 2
Only in B: 4
```

Note that this also compares files for identical contents!

Answer (score 4):

A rather comfortable graphical tool is `meld`. It is available in the repositories of many Linux distributions.

You can simply provide the directory paths you want to compare, as in

```
meld dir1/ dir2/
```

It will show a split tree view indicating which which files/directories are only present in one of the paths, and in case of files present in both paths, which of the two has a more recent timestamp.

Answer (score 4):

With `bash`, you can use:

```
diff <(cd dir1 && find -type d) <(cd dir2 && find -type d)
```

This will recursively list the directories in `dir1` and `dir2`, in alphabetical order, and compare these lists with `diff`.

Answer (score 1):

One tool you can use is `comm`, which is intended to "*compare two sorted files line by line*" (`man comm`). The two files can be the lists of directories.

Example,

```
# Set up the scenario
mkdir -p Disk_A/{A,B,C,D} Disk_B/{A,B,D,E}

# Compare the directory lists (old, new)
LC_ALL=C comm -13 <( cd Disk_A && find -type d | LC_ALL=C sort ) <( cd Disk_B && find -type d | LC_ALL=C sort )
```

Result

```
./E
```

By varying combinations of `comm`'s flags `-1`, `-2`, `-3` that omit output columns, you can also list directories in `A` but not `B` (use `-23`) or directories that are common (use `-12`).

Much like the other answers this will fail for pathological directory names such as those containing newlines. Use this extended variant if these are a possibility:

```
LC_ALL=C comm -z13 <( cd Disk_A && find -type d -print0 | LC_ALL=C sort -z ) <( cd Disk_B && find -type d -print0 | LC_ALL=C sort -z ) | tr '\0' '\n'
```

If you can guarantee that there will be no byte sequences representing invalid Unicode characters you can omit all three instances of `LC_ALL=C`, which temporarily sets the locale to `C` (bytes).

Answer (score 0):

The following shell script takes two arguments: the old directory and the new. It lists only directories which exist in the first argument and not in the second. It is, however, a little more verbose than the other solutions.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
source_dir=$1
target_dir=$2

for folder_plus_path in $( find $source_dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d ); do
  folder=${folder_plus_path#${source_dir}/}
  if [[ ! -d ${target_dir}/${folder} ]]; then
    echo ${folder}
  fi
done
```

As it stands, the above will only list missing directories *immediately* contained in the first argument (so it would hightlight that A/E does not exist, but it doesn't check that B/A/Subdir also exists as A/A/Subdir). If you want to check these sub-directories also then remove the `-maxdepth 1`  from the script.