# Can I copy a folder with a progress bar?

Tags: file-copy

I want to copy a folder with some kind of progress bar. I tried "pv" (Pipe Viewer) but it seems there is no way to copy a folder.

Actually I'm not interested in using a script for pv - I would prefer some 'ready-to-go' package.

Comment: See also [pv for directory copy](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/56047/22565)

Answer (score 4):

You could try rsync, it has a --progress option and it can copy recursively -r and -v will add more output.

```
rsync -r --progress srcdir destdir
```

Comment: This gives per file progress... Pretty useless for me, as I want to know when everything finishes

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `rsync` with the `--progress` option? You can use rsync locally - doesn't need to be across a network. [Here are some examples.](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/show-progress-during-file-transfer/)