# How to see the total progress while copying the files

Tags: rhel, rsync, command

We know that if we give --progress parameter to rsync it will show the progress of files copied. But issue is that is shows the progress for each single file not total or overall progress.

So how to see the Total progress of files copied.

Comment: Duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2577/how-can-i-move-files-and-view-the-progress-e-g-with-a-progress-bar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comments say, the question has **already been asked [here](https://serverfault.com/q/219013/158888)**.

<strike>**So... short answer: you can't.**</strike>

**EDIT:** you can now use the `--info=progress2` option of `rsync` to get an idea of overall progress (read the rest of my original answer if you are looking for an alternate progress indicator or for more info).

I'm quoting *[David Mackintosh](https://serverfault.com/a/219257/158888)*:

> There are no trivial ways to add a total progress indicator.
>
> The reason for this is that when rsync looks at a list of files to
> sync, it doesn't know ahead of time which files will need to change.
> If you are doing delta transfers, the deltas themselves have to be
> calculated ahead of time to give a total picture of the work that
> needs to be done.
>
> In other words, the easiest way to calculate how much work there is to
> be done is to actually do it.

---

But you can have a progress bar about the **number of file transferred** using `pv`, if you already know how much you have, quoting *[zerodeux](https://serverfault.com/a/279097/158888)*:

```
rsync -aix /source remote:/dest | pv -les $(df -i /source | perl -ane 'print $F[2] if $F[5] =~ m:^/:') >/dev/null
```

Comment: There is a flaw in reasoning. Nobody is really upset if progress indicator runs *faster* than it promised. Rsync can assume that it will have to transfer all source file and then, if it finds some to be transferrred, simply count it as a speed increase. It is actually realised in modern rsync versions as a `--info=progress2` option

Comment: @BarafuAlbino I didn't try that option, but it is common with `rsync` to have a speed increase factor `> 200`, which means that your progress indicator would go hundreds of times faster than expected, that is completely wrong... Except for saying that "60% of your files have been synchronized".

Answer (score 27):

To see total progress with `rsync`, the modern versions (from 3.1.0) has option `--info=progress2`. `rsync` must be running on the same machine as source files (or with NFS) for this to show sane values. Don't forget to supply `-a` option too if you copy system directories.

Comment: Is it possible to have total and per-file simultaneously?

Comment: Is it possible to have total only, without per-file?

Comment: actually, i just tried it and it seems that the values look sane even if I'm pulling files down from my server, i.e. running on a machine that's not the one with the source files.

Comment: for recursive operations (e.g. with `-a` or `-r`), the total progress can be misleading in *rsync* 3, as all nested files and subdirectories will only be discovered lazily/ad-hoc/during command execution. To get a complete estimate from the beginning, add the [`--no-inc-recursive`](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.1#opt--no-inc-recursive) option.

Answer (score 4):

[rsyncy](https://github.com/laktak/rsyncy) is a rsync wrapper that shows a status bar with progress:

[image: rsyncy]