# Deleting billions of files from a directory while seeing the progress as well

Tags: rm, progress-information

I have a directory of 30 TB having billions of files in it which are formally all JPEG files. I am deleting each folder of files like this:

```
sudo rm -rf bolands-mills-mhcptz
```

This command just runs and doesn't show anything whether it's working or not.

I want to see as it's deleting files or what is the current status of the command.

Comment: Not answers:  Sometimes it is faster to backup the stuff you want to keep, format, and restore the stuff you want to keep.  Other answers:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37329/efficiently-delete-large-directory-containing-thousands-of-files

Comment: If you just want an idea of progress, rather than knowing which particular files have been removed, you could run "df /dev/sd_whatever_the_drive_is".

Comment: How did you end up with _billions_ of files in a single directory??

Comment: In future, I suggest using a filesystem which can delete faster than ext4, such as xfs, or better yet, a next-gen filesystem such as ZFS or btrfs, where you can simply delete an entire dataset at once.

Comment: @MichaelHampton But if the files aren't a separate dataset, it may take a long time. (on ZFS) https://serverfault.com/questions/801074/delete-10m-files-from-zfs-effectively

Comment: @v7d8dpo4 If that happens, then the system wasn't planned well enough at the start.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, the last time I tried XFS, it was significantly slower than ext3 when deleting files.

Comment: Billions of files, huh? Try `rm -ri`. It will be fun!

Comment: @MichaelHampton using your logic all directories should be different datasets to avoid the chance that a program fills a directory by mistake.

Comment: @EdNeville Huh? Not all directories, just the ones that need to be.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, that's the problem, it's a great feature to destroy a FS easily, but it is useless if you cannot predict the directories that will suffer a problem.

Comment: @EdNeville In the OP's case, it's very likely that it was predictable well in advance. In fact it's predictable in most cases.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can use `rm -v` to have `rm` print one line per file deleted. This way you can see that `rm` is indeed working to delete files. But if you have billions of files then all you will see is that `rm` is still working. You will have no idea how many files are already deleted and how many are left.

The tool `pv` can help you with a progress estimation.

http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml

Here is how you would invoke `rm` with `pv` with example output

```
$ rm -rv dirname | pv -l -s 1000 > logfile
562  0:00:07 [79,8 /s] [====================>                 ] 56% ETA 0:00:05
```

In this contrived example I told `pv` that there are `1000` files. The output from `pv` shows that 562 are already deleted, elapsed time is 7 seconds, and the estimation to complete is in 5 seconds.

Some explanation:

- `pv -l` makes `pv` to count by newlines instead of bytes
- `pv -s number` tells `pv` what the total is so that it can give you an estimation.
- The redirect to `logfile` at the end is for clean output. Otherwise the status line from `pv` gets mixed up with the output from `rm -v`. Bonus: you will have a logfile of what was deleted. But beware the file will get huge. You can also redirect to `/dev/null` if you don't need a log.

To get the number of files you can use this command:

```
$ find dirname | wc -l
```

This also can take a long time if there are billions of files. You can use `pv` here as well to see how much it has counted

```
$ find dirname | pv -l | wc -l
278k 0:00:04 [56,8k/s] [     <=>                                              ]
278044
```

Here it says that it took 4 seconds to count 278k files. The exact count at the end (`278044`) is the output from `wc -l`.

If you don't want to wait for the counting then you can either guess the number of files or use `pv` without estimation:

```
$ rm -rv dirname | pv -l > logfile
```

Like this you will have no estimation to finish but at least you will see how many files are already deleted. Redirect to `/dev/null` if you don't need the logfile.

---

Nitpick:

- do you really need `sudo`?
- usually `rm -r` is enough to delete recursively. no need for `rm -f`.

Comment: Nice use of `pv`, assuming it's not too expensive to count the billions of files ;-). (It might take nearly as much time as the `rm` it's supposed to measure!)

Comment: @StephenKitt This is what really annoys me (and many other people) about the Windows file utility: it *always*, without fail, counts the number and sizes of files before deleting which, unless the drive is *much* slower than the processor, takes almost as long as the actual deletion!

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Indeed! There's more to it than that though IIRC — it checks that it *can* delete everything before deleting *anything*, to increase the chances of deletions being "all or nothing". Many years ago I wrote a filesystem driver for Windows, there were quite a few oddities we had to deal with, including some related to the way Explorer goes about deleting, but I can't remember the details. (I do remember that creating a folder involves writing and deleting a file in the new folder!)

Comment: @StephenKitt That would be why, in folders with certain permissions, I can create a folder from the command line but not Explorer. I do prefer `chmod` to the Windows file permissions system, even though I've been working with the Windows one for longer.

Comment: @StephenKitt Maybe I'm mistaken, but isn't the bottleneck, besides the disk access, the terminal output? I believe `pv` refreshes the progress bar only once per second, despite its input. So, the terminal only needs to display one line instead of a ton each second. `pv` only needs to increment a counter for each newline it encounters; that's got to be faster than doing line wrapping, and whatnot for displaying a line in a terminal. I think running with `pv` like this is causes the file removals to be faster than simply `rm -rv`.

Comment: @jlmg you're right, the output will take time. My comment stemmed from the fact that the OP's *silent* `rm` is taking a very long time already, so simply counting the files is also going to take a very long time. (Since the OP's current command is silent, terminal output isn't a bottleneck in the question.)

Comment: @StephenKitt I see. You're right that it will take slightly longer than the silent `rm`, though that's hardly avoidable to show progress as well.

Comment: @jlmg with billions of files it will take *significantly* longer.

Comment: @StephenKitt to count them? I don't think `pv` has a reason to slow down `rm`; it can probably process the lines faster than `rm` can write them. Do you mean simply because `rm` has to write them? Can the time taken to write a line to a pipe really be that comparable to that of removing a file from disk?

Comment: @StephenKitt the file name already comes with the `dirent` structure when listing out the contents of a directory, so there doesn't seem to be a need for additional disk access to write out the filepath...

Comment: @jglm I mean the whole operation will take longer: counting the files, then deleting them. I agree `rm` and `pv` shouldn't be slower than `rm` on its own; but here we're talking about adding a lengthy operation so we can track another lengthy operation, so it's worth pointing out the cost of the measurement (as lesmana has done in an edit to this answer).

Comment: @StephenKitt You were talking about doing the `find` operation first. I'm sorry; that's twice I misunderstood you. I was just thinking of `pv -l` without `pv -s`.

Comment: @StephenKitt and jlmg: Watching `df -ih` output change is definitely efficient, and doesn't require a count before-hand to show you meaningful numbers.  (And BTW, I agree writing filenames into a pipe to pv is very cheap.  It should be full-buffered, and counting lines in `pv` should be cheap (and happen on another core in a multi-threaded system).  You will almost certainly still bottleneck on disk I/O, except maybe on a slow embedded NAS CPU with fast SSDs.  Spewing lines to the terminal is what's potentially slow, even with a smart terminal emulator that skips when it falls behind.

Comment: re: last points of this answer:  `rm -f` stops it from pausing for confirmation before deleting read-only files.  POSIX requires `rm` (without `-f`) to be interactive in that case.  I agree that usually you don't need it.  I used to use `alias rm=rm -i` (and use `\rm -r foo` after I was sure I'd typed the right thing.  But now I use `alias rm=rm -I` (capital-i), which only queries if deleting 4 or more things, or deleting anything recursively.

Comment: Hey, `bash` guru! Is there any way to count files and put it after `-s` in one line (single command?)?

Comment: @skywinder `rm -rv dirname | pv -l -s $(find dirname | wc -l) > logfile`

Comment: `ls -1 -U` is also a good, fast way to get number of files

Comment: On AIX using ksh, the option is -e, 
rm -e file_to_delete

Answer (score 29):

Check out [lesmana's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/327311/86440), it's much better than mine — especially the last `pv` example, which won't take much longer than the original silent `rm` if you specify `/dev/null` instead of `logfile`.

Assuming your `rm` supports the option (it probably does since you're running Linux), you can run it in verbose mode with `-v`:

```
sudo rm -rfv bolands-mills-mhcptz
```

As has been pointed out by a number of commenters, this could be very slow because of the amount of output being generated and displayed by the terminal. You could instead redirect the output to a file:

```
sudo rm -rfv bolands-mills-mhcptz > rm-trace.txt
```

and watch the size of `rm-trace.txt`.

Comment: This can actually slow the delete down because of all the output being generated and rendered to a terminal :)

Comment: Of course it will slow down. Writing billions of lines  to a file does not happen in zero time.

Answer (score 23):

Another option is to watch the number of files on the filesystem decrease.  In another terminal, run:

```
watch  df -ih   pathname
```

The used-inodes count will decrease as `rm` makes progress.  (Unless the files mostly had multiple links, e.g. if the tree was created with `cp -al`).  This tracks deletion progress in terms of number-of-files (and directories).  `df` without `-i` will track in terms of space used.

You could also run `iostat -x 4` to see I/O operations per second (as well as kiB/s, but that's not very relevant for pure metadata I/O).

---

If you get curious about what files `rm` is currently working on, you can attach an `strace` to it and watch as the `unlink()` (and getdents) system calls spew on your terminal.  e.g. `sudo strace -p $(pidof rm)`.  You can `^c` the strace to detach from `rm` without interrupting it.

I forget if `rm -r` changes directory into the tree it's deleting; if so you could look at `/proc/<PID>/cwd`.  Its `/proc/<PID>/fd` might often have a directory fd open, so you could look at that to see what your `rm` process is currently looking at.

Comment: `df -ih` is indeed a nice cheap way of watching `rm` progress.

Comment: BTW, this doesn't work on BTRFS, where the used-inode count is always zero.  :(  Same for FAT32, but you probably don't have billions of files on your `/boot` EFI system partition.

Comment: if you don't have watch, this seems to do ok -- `for (( ; ; )); do; clear; df -ih /path/to/dir; sleep 5; done`

Answer (score 5):

While the above answers all use `rm`, `rm` can actually be quite slow at deleting a large numbers of files, as I recently observed when extracting ~100K files from a .tar archive actually took less time than deleting them. Although this does not actually answer the question you asked, a better solution to your problem might be to use a different method to delete your files, such as one of the upvoted answers to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/183821/rm-on-a-directory-with-millions-of-files).

My personal favorite method is to use `rsync -a --delete`. I find that this method performs fast enough that it's worth the ease-of-use over [the most upvoted answer to that question](https://serverfault.com/a/328305/360402), in which the author has written a C program that you would need to compile. (Note that this will output every file being processed to stdout, much like `rm -rv`; this can slow down the process by a surprising amount. If you do not want this output, use `rsync -aq --delete` or redirect the output to a file instead.)

The author of that answer says:

> The program will now (on my system) delete 1000000 files in 43 seconds. The closest program to this was rsync -a --delete which took 60 seconds (which also does deletions in-order, too but does not perform an efficient directory lookup).

I have found that this is good enough for my purposes. Also potentially important from that answer, at least if you're using ext4:

> As a forethought, one should remove the affected directory and remake it after. Directories only ever increase in size and can remain poorly performing even with a few files inside due to the size of the directory.

Comment: huh, I would have expected `rm` and/or `find --delete` to be efficient.  Interesting point about deleting in sort order to avoid b-tree rebalances while deleting.  Not sure how much of that applies to other filesystems.  XFS is also not great with millions of files per directory.  IDK about BTRFS, but I'm under the impression that it might be good for that sort of thing.

Comment: Doesn't that second quote depend on the type of filesystem...

Comment: @Menasheh Good point, I edited that into my answer.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you could do would be to start up the `rm` process in the background (with no output, so it won't be slowed down) and then, monitor it in the foreground with a simple<sup>(a)</sup> command:

```
pax> ( D=/path/to/dir ; rm -rf $D & while true ; do
...>   if [[ -d $D ]] ; then
...>     echo "$(find $D | wc -l) items left"
...>   else
...>     echo "No items left"
...>     break
...>   fi
...>   sleep 5
...> done )

27912 items left
224 items left
No items left

pax> _
```

The `find/wc` combo could be replaced with any tool able to give you the units you want.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Well, *relatively* simple, compared to, say, nuclear physics, the Riemann hypothesis, or what to buy my wife for Xmas :-)

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I wrote something to print the rate that lines were printed. You can run `rm -rfv | ./counter` and it will print lines per sec/min. Although not a direct progress, it will give you some feedback on the progress rate, maybe the `rm` wandered into a network filesystem or similar perhaps?

Link to the code is here:

http://www.usenix.org.uk/code/counter-0.01.tar.gz