# Are there any "richer" alternatives to cp and mv (like bat to cat and exa to ls)?

Tags: cp, mv, coreutils, alternatives

`ls` has [exa](https://github.com/ogham/exa). `cat` has [bat](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat). I don't know of a direct alternative to `rm`, but it also has [rmtrash](https://github.com/PhrozenByte/rmtrash).

All of these can usually work as drop-in alias replacements, retaining usual function and options of their commands but also including additional options, better highlighting and formatting and better defaults.

I still use the much more portable builtins in scripts, but richer commands make day-to-day shell use much more comfortable.

Are there such alternatives to `cp` and `mv`?
The main feature that comes to mind is a progress bar, but another one would be a better overview of the action in interactive mode, and I'm sure there are many more potential improvements.

Comment: I've been using MC for that (even since Volcov Commander/Norton Commander/Dos Navigator/Far File Manager). I don't understand why people insist on using cp and mv with which you can easily make stupid mistakes and lose a lot of data. Check this as well: https://askubuntu.com/questions/17275/how-to-show-the-transfer-progress-and-speed-when-copying-files-with-cp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I move files and view the progress (e.g. with a progress bar)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2577/how-can-i-move-files-and-view-the-progress-e-g-with-a-progress-bar)

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov This is interesting, but it does not exactly answer my question. I'm looking for fully fledged alternatives that are created to be a kind of "modern" version of the old commands, with extra features that make behaviour overall more user friendly. While one such feature would be a progress bar, it's not specifically what I'm looking for. Thanks for the links though!

Comment: `grep` has `ripgrep` which works very fast.