# Display transfer speed when performing "cp" from the command line?

Tags: command-line, cp, file-transfer

Is this possible?

Comment: Interesting that this is marked as a duplicate of a question asked 3 years later?

Answer (score 53):

The standard coreutils `cp` command doesn't support this. There's a Gentoo patch floating around that adds it for different versions, although it's not included in Gentoo anymore for some reason; the version for coreutils 6.10 is [in their bugzilla](http://bugs.gentoo.org/attachment.cgi?id=182615&action=view), and I'm sure there are lots of others around.

If you don't want to patch `cp`, you need to use some other command. For example, `rsync` has a `--progress` flag, so you can do:

```
rsync --progress source destination
```

If instead of copying you cat the data and then redirect stdout to the destination (i.e. `cat source > destination`), then you can use a program that measures pipe throughput and insert it in the middle (`cat source | SOME-PROGRAM > destination`); there are a couple mentioned in [this related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1537/73). The one I recommended there was [pv](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) (Pipe Viewer):

[image: Screenshot of pv from the pv homepage]

If you give it the `--rate` flag it will show the transfer rate

Comment: Very interesting, although not worth the effort.  I merely would like cp <source> <dest> to provide a rate similar to how it would report transfer rate using the GUI.  Not worth the effort to type that much text just to see the transfer speed.  Thanks though.

Comment: @Chris Well, you can always add a function for it. `function cprate() {cat "$1" | pv --rate > "$2"}`

Comment: `pv` seems good, but I tried it for the same reason as the poster (progress/rate when copying to nfs), where the file gets crated in tmp and transferred afterwards. So, instead of nfs I have to use smb to see progess and rates.

Comment: Using "cat" is a very dangerous method, I have experienced that cat on some AIX Systems will cut out what they interpret as garbage. Depending on the character set you chose by default. I would agree totally with rsync!

Answer (score 20):

I find that using pv in this manner works well for that purpose

```
pv -p file1 > file2
```

The `-p` switch shows the file transfer progress. To see the transfer speed, add the `-r` switch. If you want to see the average transfer rate over time, you can use the `-a` switch.

```
pv -pra file1 > file2
```

Comment: pv? <filler text>

Comment: `pv` is [Pipe Viewer](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml), and is pretty awesome. @Patrick, please expand your post with an explanation.

Comment: This is the same command I mentioned in my answer, although I didn't realize it takes a filename argument (I did `cat file | pv`)

Comment: Good explanation: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/unix-utilities-pipe-viewer/

Comment: It seems to measure only the read speed and not the write speed, as it writes only to cache (even for a several GB sized file)

Answer (score 10):

I know this is rather old, but...

If you do not actually want to display the rate, but only want to watch if something is happening on copying of a large file, you can also just use the `watch` command (also works with `mv`):

```
cp /path/to/myfile /path/to/target/myfile
```

Then, in another shell, or pushing the copy-command to the background (e.g. with `Ctrl + Z` followed by `bg`), you can check the result with:

```
watch "ls -sh1 /path/to/target"
```

This will continuously update the output of the `ls` command update (by default every 2.0s), displaying something like:

```
Every 2.0s: ls -sh1 /path/to/target                                      
Tue Jan 12 15:02:45 2016

total 1.1G
4.0K data
130M tmp1.txt
137M tmp2.txt
151M tmp3.txt
168M tmp4.txt
162M myFile
```

Comment: This is a neat hack. Although mine shows Every 2s. And I don't think it is accurate.

Comment: Thanks - if we have already started the command this really is the only way to avoid checkign the file size manually every few secs :)

Comment: Also there's a -n option to specify a value larger than 2 secs

Comment: @GeneCode -n switch in the watch command allows to set the update interva in secondsl (also fractions like 0.5 are usually possible). the -h in the ls command makes output "human readable"... you can leave that out if you want byte counts :-)

Answer (score 5):

Hi Another way to show the transfer speed is to use `scp` on localhost like this:
`scp -rv src_folder user@localhost:/dest_folder`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that uses `du` to monitor throughput. This is more application agnostic and is also referenced in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/301490/183269. Execute the script on the destination host.

```bash
monitorio () {
# show write speed for file or directory
    interval="10"
    target="$1"
    size=$(du -ks "$target" | awk '{print $1}')
    firstrun="1"
    echo ""
    while [ 1 ]; do
        prevsize=$size
        size=$(du -ks "$target" | awk '{print $1}')
        #size=$(ls -l "$1"  | awk '{print $5/1024}')
        kb=$((${size} - ${prevsize}))
        kbmin=$((${kb}* (60/${interval}) ))
        kbhour=$((${kbmin}*60))
        # exit if this is not first loop & file size has not changed
        if [ $firstrun -ne 1 ] && [ $kb -eq 0 ]; then break; fi
        echo -e "\e[1A $target changed ${kb}KB ${kbmin}KB/min ${kbhour}KB/hour size: ${size}KB"
        firstrun=0
        sleep $interval
    done
}
```

example use:

```
user@host:~$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/zero bs=1 count=50000000 &
user@host:~$ monitorio /tmp/zero
/tmp/zero changed 4KB 24KB/min 1440KB/hour size: 4164KB
/tmp/zero changed 9168KB 55008KB/min 3300480KB/hour size: 13332KB
/tmp/zero changed 9276KB 55656KB/min 3339360KB/hour size: 22608KB
/tmp/zero changed 8856KB 53136KB/min 3188160KB/hour size: 31464KB
^C
user@host:~$ killall dd; rm /tmp/zero
```