# Is it possible to see cp speed and percent copied?

Tags: cp

I'm having problems when copying large files using nautilus (it gets stuck). I need to copy, using `cp`. I would like to know if there are any parameters that shows the % copied and also the transfer speed.

Comment: `Midnight Commander` also works well, and has a pretty text-based UI with progress bars, but might not be installed. Try `mc` on the command prompt. Also, obviously, it's not `cp`.

Comment: Using `rsync` with `--progress` just made me figure out what is happening. It gets stuck when it reaches the 100%, and then last a couple of minutes in end up. I think is the same that is happening with nautilus. Anyway that is another question already, so the best answer for this question is the `rsync --progress`, it shows size, %, speed and elapsed time.

Comment: I have a question about the `rsync --progress`. Assume that I have the directory A with files a and b and the empty directory B, when I copy A to B it shows the progress of each file, i.e. the progress of a and the progress of b. Is there any way to show the overall progress?

Comment: one problem with rsync is that it runs slower than a pure copy.  On my big server, the difference is 60MB/s and 300MB/s respectively.

Comment: @pdwalker even with the `-W` option?  on all my hosts `rsync` is almost as fast as `cp` ... so close i regularly use `rsync` instead of `cp`.

Comment: See also: [AskUbuntu: How to show the transfer progress and speed when copying files with cp?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17275/how-to-show-the-transfer-progress-and-speed-when-copying-files-with-cp)

Answer (score 279, accepted):

`rsync` version 3.0.9+ has a `--progress` flag, which shows progress per file:

```
rsync --progress SOURCE DEST
```

`rsync` of any version has a `--info=progress2` flag, which shows the overall percentage:

```
rsync --info=progress2 SOURCE DEST
```

Comment: --info=progress2 still hasn't made it into a default repository and here it is 2015. Seems like a good idea.

Comment: `--info=progress2` finally included on `version 3.1.0  protocol version 31`. Maybe you could edit your answer, yzT.

Comment: I noticed from `--info=progress2` that rsync is blazing fast! 200 MB/s, while Windows goesn't further than 90 MB/s!

Comment: @ReneFroger although that might be the real speed (depending on device), often in Linux that fast speed is really false, and after the copy has been finished the system is still writing to the device, unlike in Windows that you can eject the device almost immediately. If you copy large files you can notice how it start at that fast speed but then it goes down till the standard one.

Comment: it worked for me with just `--progress`. rsync version 3.0.9

Comment: What if my linux don't have rsync?

Comment: rsync consumes a lot of bandwidth, I see as much in as out, what makes it not useful for over network copy which is my case.

Comment: `rsync --info=progress2 source dest` produces error `skipping directory source`. You must add a `-r` or `-a` option, or similar, to fix this. I recommend `-a` and also adding `--stats` to show a nice output summary at the end. Lastly, add `time` in front to see how long the total process took. So, do this instead: `time rsync -a --info=progress2 --stats source destination`. Using this command I just duplicated a 42GB directory within a fast SSD drive in ~2.5 minutes! Incredible!

Comment: I decided to just make this another answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65077/is-it-possible-to-see-cp-speed-and-percent-copied/567828#567828.

Comment: @fguillen, use the `-z` option to use compression and reduce bandwidth over the network.

Answer (score 118):

If you allow other tools than `cp` it's surely possible. For a single file you can use `pv`. It's a small tool providing nice statistics.

```
pv inputfile > outputfile
```

If you have multiple files or directories you can use tar:

```
tar c sourceDirectory | pv | tar x -C destinationDirectory
```

You can wrap it in a shell function. It's less to type and you get semantics close to the ones of `cp`. Here's a very simple (and not error-proof!) function:

```
cpstat () {
  tar c "$1" | pv | tar x -C "$2"
}
```

Note that some versions of `tar` don't support the abovementioned syntax (e.g. Solaris `tar`) and you have to use the following variant:

```
cpstat () {
  tar cf - "$1" | pv | (cd "$2";tar xf -)
}
```

You call it like this

```
cpstat sourceDirectory destinationDirectory
```

You can enhance it further, so that `pv` provides an estimation of the remaining time.

Another solution (as frostschutz mentioned in a comment) is to use rsync with the `--progress` option:

```
rsync --progress -a sourceDirectory destinationDirectory
```

Comment: This will give you transfer speed, but not ETA, because `pv` doesn't know how much data will come through the pipe. You can specify this using `-s`. E.g. first do `du -sh sourceDirectory` to get a (rough) idea, and then pass it to `pv`, like this: `pv -s 100m`.

Comment: --info=progress2 gives you directory level progress statistics.

Comment: `vbuf` (debian, ubuntu) is a good bit faster than `pv`, probably because of its virtual ring buffer

Comment: @Skaperen I don't know `vbuf`. But as it seems it is in Debian unstable at the moment and therefore often not available on Servers which are usually running Debian stable.

Comment: Of you want speed, amount copied, % copied, time, and ETA: `cat $1 | pv -a -r -b -p -e -s $(stat --printf="%s" $1) > $2` Note that `pv` will slow it down if you have very fast disks.

Comment: Has `pv` changed in recent years? Now something like `pv file0 > file1` shows ETA, transfer speed, time elapsed, a progress bar, _and_ total bytes transferred.

Answer (score 73):

`rsync` works the best for showing the progress during the copying progress.

ex:

```
rsync -avh --progress sourceDirectory destinationDirectory
```

Answer (score 59):

> Is it possible to see cp speed and percent copied?

Yes, it is possible to display the progress of the command `cp` on the terminal.

---

### Method #1: (use `progress`)

Open a new terminal and type `progress` it will display the progress of `cp` command and others command such as:

`cp, mv, dd, tar, cat, rsync, grep, fgrep, egrep, cut, sort, md5sum, sha1sum, sha224sum, sha256sum, sha384sum, sha512sum, adb, gzip, gunzip, bzip2, bunzip2, xz, unxz, lzma, unlzma, 7z, zcat, bzcat, lzcat, split, gpg`

If you didn't install `progress`, you can install it from repository, for example in the `CentOS` with this command: `yum -y install progress`.

Then after you run `cp` command in the background, or after run `cp` normally, open another terminal, so just try this command:

```
# progress -m
```

**See output:**

```
[30904] cp /home/user/file.mp4
        2.3% (200.9 MiB / 8.4 GiB) 3.6 MiB/s remaining 0:38:58
```

---

### Method #2: (use patch `cp`)

Or download the GNU `coreutils` and patch it.

```
cd /tmp
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/coreutils-8.21.tar.xz
tar -xvJf coreutils-8.21.tar.xz
cd coreutils-8.21
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/atdt/advcpmv/master/advcpmv-0.5-8.21.patch
patch -p1 -i advcpmv-0.5-8.21.patch
```

Run:

```
export FORCE_UNSAFE_CONFIGURE=1
./configure
make
```

Copy the two files `cp` and `mv` loacated under `coreutils-8.21/src/` to `/usr/local/bin`:

```
cp src/cp /usr/local/bin/cp
cp src/mv /usr/local/bin/mv
```

Or copy it using your file manager as root

Add the following lines to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias cp='cp -gR'
alias mv='mv -g'
```

Logout and Login

The progress bar can be displayed without the `–g` or `–progress-bar` as recommended by the Author

**See output:**

```
0 files copied so far...                                              194.4 MiB /   8.4 GiB
[||--------------------------------------------------------------------------------]  2.3 %
Copying at   3.3 MiB/s (about 0h 5m 47s remaining)
/home/user/file.mp4                                                   194.4 MiB / 446.1 MiB
[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||----------------------------------------------] 43.6 %
```

[**Source:linuxhelp**](https://www.linuxhelp.com/install-advanced-copy-command-show-progress-bar-linux/)

Comment: This looks like the true source of the `cp` patch: https://web.archive.org/web/20131115171331/http://beatex.org/web/advancedcopy.html

Comment: To fix  "Please port gnulib fseeko.c to your platform!" error , please see https://github.com/fede2cr/slackware_riscv/issues/2#issuecomment-441414025

Comment: The original patched cp no longer exists, here is a maintained version https://github.com/jarun/advcpmv

Comment: method 1 is so nice. no need to alter commands, zero room for error.

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, how does `progress` work?

Comment: This is the canonical answer since it answers the question in the scope of its tag

Answer (score 35):

As explained in other answers, cp doesn't provide that functionality. However, [progress (formerly called cv)](https://github.com/Xfennec/progress) is a small tool which is very helpful in providing this missing feature.

> This tool can be described as a Tiny Dirty Linux Only* C command that looks for coreutils basic commands (cp, mv, dd, tar, gzip/gunzip, cat, ...) currently running on your system and displays the percentage of copied data.

I've been using it for the past few months and it's solid.

Comment: doesn't seem to work with all filesystems (e.g. cifs) but +1, didn't know such crazy ting exits

Comment: Note that this project is now called "progress - Coreutils Progress Viewer (formerly known as cv)".

Comment: This progress tool appears to be fairly rudimentary. I just tried it to monitor the progress of a large `cp -a` job copying many files and directories (recursive). It seems to be only capable of showing the progress of the currently copying file, not the whole `cp` job.

Comment: `progress` is another one of these underappreciated tools that the unix world is full of.

Answer (score 16):

Noticed this posting was somewhat old. But as I made a solution to the issue at hand, I thought I'd post my solution.

Scenario: We have a very large directory-structure we want to copy, so we issue the command cp -R sourcedir destdir in one terminal window.

Open another terminal window or push the process to the background `(Ctrl+Z,bg<CR>)`, then let's make a progress indicator the ghetto way:

We first get the total size of the directory structure we want to copy, you do this with:

`du -sh /path/sourcedirectory/`

Convert the result to gigabytes (G), then substitute the n for the result you got in the variable sourcesize. Once you've inserted the sourcesize and destdir (destination directory), run the command below.

```
while true; do sourcesize=n destdir=/path/destinationdirectory/ copyprogress="$(export | du -sh $destdir | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/[^0-9.]*//g' )" ; echo "scale=3 ; $copyprogress / $sourcesize * 100" | bc | xargs echo -n ; echo % completed ; sleep 10 ; done
```

This will print the progress every 10 seconds with messages like:

```
0.100% completed
0.200% completed
0.300% completed 
... etc
```

I'm aware that this solution did not address the speed of copying, but it would be possible to add that by by expanding the commands above, possibly making it into a bash script so it would be easier to read. For instance by checking how much data is copied pr. n time unit, the speed should be trivial to calculate and display.

Comment: This is actually perfect for my use case, so thanks for posting it! I want to know about the progress of copying a huge directory with thousands of files, not just one file, so the other solutions don't really help me.

Comment: This is great, especially in cases such as the one I am experiencing right now: Remotely started a huge mv-job to move terrabytes of backups from one storage pool to another, without thinking about the implications beforehand. Now I can easily background the process and peek in on it. Awesome!

Answer (score 10):

To improve on Marco's answer, today I wrote this version of `cpstat`, so you can copy many directories and use the last parameter as the destination path. Note that if you use a relative deep path as source, you can, thanks to `tar`, automatically create the same dependent directory tree.

```
function cpstat () {

    tar -cf - "${@: 1: $#-1}" |
    pv -s "$( du -cs -BK --apparent-size "${@: 1: $#-1}" |
              tail -n 1 |
              cut -d "$(echo -e "\t")" -f 1)" |
    ( cd "${@: $#}"; tar -xf - )

;}
```

Answer (score 7):

**`dd status=progress`**

Option added in GNU Coreutils 8.24+ (Ubuntu 16.04):

```
dd if=src of=dst status=progress
```

Stdout is a periodically updated line like:

```
462858752 bytes (463 MB, 441 MiB) copied, 38 s, 12,2 MB/s
```

See also: [How do you monitor the progress of dd? | Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215505/how-do-you-monitor-the-progress-of-dd)

Answer (score 6):

Not in a standard version of [`cp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cp).

You could [background the cp and list](http://www.unix.com/302197445-post2.html) the size while waiting for `cp` to finish.

I use [this perl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64663/22470) to monitor growth of a single file but it runs externally to the cp (or whatever else I'm doing)

Answer (score 6):

I found this to use, worked great:

```
sudo watch lsof -p`pgrep -x cp`
```

from a comment by [Mike](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/10457/mike) on the question [how to check progress of running cp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66795/how-to-check-progress-of-running-cp)

Answer (score 5):

Another simple solution is to just [watch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch) the output folder as follows:

**Linux/Cygwin:**
`watch -n 10 --differences du -sk --apparent-size <WATCHED_FOLDER>`

**FreeBSD:**
`gnu-watch -n 10 --differences du -sk <WATCHED_FOLDER>`

This handy utility will run `du` and highlight the differences.

One other potential solution would be to write a simple script that loops, calling `du` and spitting out a rough estimate of the throughput.

Answer (score 5):

Even though `rsync` will give you some progress stats, if you want a progress bar you should use `pv`.

You can use `cpv`, a wrapper for `pv` with an easier syntax, more similar to that of `cp` that you can use to recursively copy directories

[image]

You can get it [here](https://ownyourbits.com/2017/09/13/copy-with-a-progress-bar-with-cpv/)

Answer (score 4):

Using a tool like `mc` (midnight commander) can be a good alternate option to other answers.

It's a simple file manager that shows you copy / move progress.

Answer (score 3):

I just had a case where cp was more or less blocked due to a FUSE bug in the receiving filesystem.

If you can't just switch from cp (i.e. because --sparse=always) and want something that is actually reliable for progress, go via /proc.

```
Every 2.0s: cat /proc/20977/io                                                      Thu Sep 28 04:08:57 2017

rchar: 268573800
wchar: 268500992
syscr: 4112
syscw: 4097
read_bytes: 268697600
write_bytes: 0
cancelled_write_bytes: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use rsync. However, `rsync --info=progress2 source dest` produces error `skipping directory source`. You must add a `-r` or `-a` option, or similar, to fix this. I recommend `-a` and also adding `--stats` to show a nice output summary at the end. Lastly, add `time` in front to see how long the total process took.

So, do this instead:

```
time rsync -a --info=progress2 --stats source destination
```

See [my other answer here for more details](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17275/how-to-show-the-transfer-progress-and-speed-when-copying-files-with-cp/1275972#1275972).

Using this command I just duplicated a 42GB directory within a fast SSD drive in ~2.5 minutes! Incredible!

Here's the output. Notice that the "real" time this run took was 2.798 seconds. That's because I forgot to use `time` on the first run where it actually did the copy, so this is just what the output looks like when everything is already the same in source and destination.

```
$ time rsync -a --info=progress2 --stats mydir mydir_copy
              0   0%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#0, to-chk=0/289187)   

Number of files: 289,187 (reg: 266,595, dir: 22,580, link: 12)
Number of created files: 0
Number of deleted files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 0
Total file size: 48,621,942,935 bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 2,096,688
File list generation time: 0.017 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 11,036,784
Total bytes received: 24,420

sent 11,036,784 bytes  received 24,420 bytes  4,424,481.60 bytes/sec
total size is 48,621,942,935  speedup is 4,395.72

real    0m2.798s
user    0m1.115s
sys 0m1.935s
```

UPDATE:

Here's what it looks like doing a full copy of a 48GB folder. It took 3 min 13.408 sec!

```
$ time rsync -a --info=progress2 --stats mydir mydir_bak
 48,621,942,066  99%  239.88MB/s    0:03:13 (xfr#266595, to-chk=0/289188)   

Number of files: 289,188 (reg: 266,595, dir: 22,581, link: 12)
Number of created files: 289,188 (reg: 266,595, dir: 22,581, link: 12)
Number of deleted files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 266,595
Total file size: 48,621,942,935 bytes
Total transferred file size: 48,621,942,066 bytes
Literal data: 48,621,942,066 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 12,515,323
File list generation time: 0.034 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 48,656,219,349
Total bytes received: 5,209,801

sent 48,656,219,349 bytes  received 5,209,801 bytes  251,480,254.01 bytes/sec
total size is 48,621,942,935  speedup is 1.00

real    3m13.408s
user    2m40.937s
sys 1m0.627s
```

## Related:

1. [my answer] **Detailed description and examples of many ways to use rsync, including mirroring** (with deletion not just addition of files): https://superuser.com/questions/1271882/convert-ntfs-partition-to-ext4-how-to-copy-the-data/1464264#1464264
2. [my answer] https://askubuntu.com/questions/17275/how-to-show-the-transfer-progress-and-speed-when-copying-files-with-cp/1275972#1275972

Answer (score 1):

> VCP – copy files in a curses interface (Show the Progress Bar in Linux).
>
> **DESCRIPTION:** vcp  copies files and directories in a curses interface,
>   with text only output available. 
>   its options and output are similar to BSD's cp while adding some new features.
>
> It provides information on:
>
> - files copied and left to copy
> - data written and total data size
> - data being written every second
> - two status bars, one showing current file status, the other total status
>          (except with 1 file, both show current), and percentage
>
> when output is sent to the console:
>
> - a status bar
> - size copied and speed

VCP man page: https://linux.die.net/man/1/vcp

Download vcp-2.2.tar.gz from:

http://distfiles.gentoo.org/distfiles/vcp-2.2.tar.gz

Dependence: curses.h (libncurses-dev).

On Ubuntu, install:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

---

### INSTALL vcp:

```
make && make install
```

---

### Manual:

```
man vcp
```

Answer (score 1):

With BSD `cp`, if you use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> you will get an update on the percentage, if you must use `cp`

Comment: unfortunately this works only with BSD cp, not with GNU one.

Answer (score 0):

On specific appliances like VMWare ESXi where you either have no control over what's installed or have no rights to install, you can see percentage per file and speed by using scp on localhost instead of plain `cp`:

```
scp -rv item-to-copy your-user@127.0.0.1:/path/to/destination
```

[image: scp on ESX]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search engine results, and the OP will need to type-copy command examples when trying to apply your solution. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.

Comment: oh, my bad, i used screenshot to show what  output is like using above command on an ESX server. command used is writen on answer but I'll take note on formatting.