# How to check progress of running cp?

Tags: cp

Is it possible to check the progress of running cp process? Some processes respond to various KILL signals so that you can check what is their status. I know that I can run cp with parameter -v but what if forgot to do that, cp is running for a very long time and I want to know which file is being copied, or how many were already copied.

Comment: Most solutions (on Linux and probably other POSIX, like Mac OS X) get off-track when read operations are much faster than write operations, displaying 100% far before the actual completion. The reason is write operations sit in filesystem cache before they are actually performed. At that point, things are difficult to track. This trick may reduce the gap: in another terminal `while sleep 1 ; do sync ; done` .

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, by running stat on target file and local file, and get a file size,

i.e `stat -c "%s" /bin/ls`

And you get the percentage of data copied by comparing the two value, that's it

In a very basic implementation that will look like this:

```sh
function cpstat()
{
  local pid="${1:-$(pgrep -xn cp)}" src dst
  [[ "$pid" ]] || return
  while [[ -f "/proc/$pid/fd/3" ]]; do
    read src dst < <(stat -L --printf '%s ' "/proc/$pid/fd/"{3,4})
    (( src )) || break
    printf 'cp %d%%\r' $((dst*100/src))
    sleep 1
  done
  echo
}
```

Comment: not intended to post a duplicate of your suggestion, so I added the code here. Hope you not mind.

Comment: @manatwork ah thanks, I was just being lazy in giving a complete example :-)

Comment: Excellent, this is going in my toolbox on all servers!  Thanks!

Comment: on linux 4, cp'ing from one fast usb drive to a cheap micro sd on a old card reader a 500mb file: cp and sync hangs for several dozen minutes. but if I stat the source and destination file I get the exact same number on both 10s after cp started.

Comment: Answer is ok but downvoting as it's the accepted answer but not obvious the approach works when copying tens of thousands of small files where as this answer does: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102133/29407

Answer (score 63):

On recent versions of Mac OS X you can just hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to see progress.
From the [OSX 10.6 man page for cp(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cp.1.html):

```
 "If cp receives a SIGINFO (see the status argument for stty(1)) signal,
 the current input and output file and the percentage complete will be
 written to the standard output."
```

Hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> is equivalent to signaling the current process with SIGINFO
on BSD-ish machines, including OSX.

This works for [dd(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dd.1.html) as well.

I don't think Linux has this SIGINFO mechanism, and don't see anything
in the [GNU man page for cp(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cp) about signals that can be used to report
progress.

Comment: Wow! It doesn't give me much information, but it's enough to know my `mv` is alive. Thanks!

Comment: It only tells you the percent complete for the individual file that it is copying when it receives the signal.  It does not give the percent complete of the entire job it is doing.

Comment: If the process is running in the background, `kill -s SIGINFO <PID>` works as well. Tested on FreeNAS, but it should apply to macOS as well.

Comment: For Linux Users:
https://stuff-things.net/2016/04/06/that-one-stupid-dd-trick-and-the-ballad-of-siginfo/
says: "The trick is this, by sending the dd process SIGUSR1 (Linux) or SIGINFO (BSD, OS X), you can get it to display a version of the “final” status at any time."
The author uses two variations: `kill -SIGUSR1 13747` and `kill -USR1 $dd_pid`

Comment: WARNING: Sending SIGUSR1 on Linux may work with 'dd', but for 'cp' it killed the process, outputting "User defined signal 1" as it died.

Answer (score 30):

When you're copying a lot of files, `du -s /path/to/destination` or `find /path/to/destination | wc -l` gives you an idea of how much has already been done.

You can find out which file is being copied with `lsof -p1234` where 1234 is the process ID of `cp`. Under many systems, `pgrep -x cp` reports the process IDs of all running processes named `cp`. This may not be very useful as the order in which the files inside a given directory are copied is essentially unpredictable (in a large directory under Linux, `ls --sort=none` will tell you; with a directory tree, try `find`).

`lsof -p1234` also tells you how many bytes `cp` has already read and written for the current file, in the `OFFSET` column.

Under Linux, there are IO usage statistics in `/proc/$pid/io` (again, use the PID of the `cp` process for `$pidf`). The `rchar` value is the total number of bytes that the process has read, and `wchar` is the number of bytes that the process has written. This includes not only data in files but also metadata in directories. You can compare that figure with the approximate figure obtained with `du /path/to/source` (which only counts file data).
 `read_bytes` and `write_bytes` only include what has been read or written from storage, i.e. it excludes terminal diagnostics and data already in cache or still in buffers.

Comment: for real time: `watch lsof -p1234`

Comment: Or all in one go: ``watch lsof -p`pgrep -x cp` ``

Comment: @mchid Your comment should be an accepted answer, as it provides real time insight on what's being copied, very useful for big copy jobs with millions of files

Answer (score 26):

A relatively new tool that does exactly that is [progress](https://github.com/Xfennec/progress) (formerly cv [coreutils viewer]).

What is it?

> This tool can be described as a Tiny, Dirty, Linux-and-OSX-Only C command that looks for coreutils basic commands (cp, mv, dd, tar, gzip/gunzip, cat, etc.) currently running on your system and displays the percentage of copied data.

How does it work?

> It simply scans `/proc` for interesting commands, and then looks at directories `fd` and `fdinfo` to find opened files and seek positions, and reports status for the largest file.

Comment: This util is now called progress: https://github.com/Xfennec/progress

Answer (score 19):

One of my favorite tricks for this (under Linux) is to find out the PID of the `cp` process (using `ps | grep cp` or similar), and then to look in `/proc/$PID/fd/` and `/proc/$PID/fdinfo/`.

```
$ cp -r y z
^Z
$ ls -l /proc/8614/fd
lrwx------ 1 jander jander 64 Aug  2 15:21 0 -> /dev/pts/4
lrwx------ 1 jander jander 64 Aug  2 15:21 1 -> /dev/pts/4
lrwx------ 1 jander jander 64 Aug  2 15:20 2 -> /dev/pts/4
lr-x------ 1 jander jander 64 Aug  2 15:21 3 -> /home/jander/y/foo.tgz
l-wx------ 1 jander jander 64 Aug  2 15:21 4 -> /home/jander/z/foo.tgz
```

This will show you what files the process has open.  If you want to see how far into the file the process is...

```
$ cat /proc/8614/fdinfo/3
pos:    105381888
flags:  0500000
```

the `pos` parameter is the position of the read (or write) pointer, in bytes.

Answer (score 10):

While the OP has specifically mentioned the ability to see how the "cp" command is progressing, it must be said that other utilities are better for this particular issue.

For example:

```
rsync -avP FROM TO
```

will show the progress of copying the FROM file/folder to the TO file/FOLDER.

---

```
# rsync -avP Video.mp4  /run/media/user1/3.8G/

sending incremental file list
Video.mp4
    565,170,046 100%   51.23MB/s    0:00:10 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)

sent 565,308,115 bytes  received 134 bytes  5,210,214.28 bytes/sec
total size is 565,170,046  speedup is 1.00
```

---

And rsync will tell you how much it's copied (and the transfer rate) along the way. It works for single files or folder both on the same machine or across the network.

Comment: You're answering the wrong question. The question you are looking for is: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2577/how-can-i-move-files-and-view-the-progress-e-g-with-a-progress-bar, which already has an answer mentioning `rsync`.

Answer (score 7):

There are a few things you can do.  You could attach `strace` to it to see what it's doing (output may be copious!):

```
strace -p [pid of cp]
```

or you could get `lsof` to tell you which files it currently has open:

```
lsof -p [pid of cp]
```

If you're running a big recursive `cp`, you could use `pwdx` to get the current working directory, which may give you some idea of how it's doing:

```
pwdx [pid of cp]
```

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add `cpv`, a little wrapper for `pv` that I wrote that imitates the usage of `cp`.

Simple and useful

[image]

You can get it [here](https://ownyourbits.com/2017/09/13/copy-with-a-progress-bar-with-cpv/)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is check the files at destination.

If your cp commands is something like `cp -a <my_source> <my_dest_folder>` I would check which files are already copied in `<my_dest_folder>` and each file size, so I can see the progress. If the `<my_source>` is a bit complex (several layers of directories) then a small script would be able to check the status. Although such a script could consume a bit of I/O that would then not be used by the `cp` process.

Answer (score 1):

This tool is a Linux utility command that looks for coreutils basic commands (cp, mv, dd, tar, gzip/gunzip, cat, etc.) currently running on your system and displays the percentage of copied data:

https://github.com/Xfennec/cv

Answer (score 1):

Use `pv -d`:

> `-d PID[:FD], --watchfd PID[:FD]`
>   Instead of transferring data, watch file descriptor `FD` of process `PID`, and show its progress. […] If only a `PID` is specified, then that process will be watched, and all regular files and block devices it opens will be shown with a progress bar. The `pv` process will exit when process `PID` exits.

<sup>([source](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pv.1.html))</sup>

Find out the PID of your running `cp` (`pidof cp`), let's say it's 12345; then simply

```
pv -d 12345
```

Notes:

- Run `pv` as the same user who runs `cp` (or as root).
- Since copying means reading one file and writing to the other, expect to see two files being monitored at a time.
- If `cp` is processing small files at the moment, you will probably not see all of them in the output (a small file may get closed too fast for `pv` to pick it up). Yet some will appear, so even then you will be able to tell what `cp` does.
- `pv -d "$(pidof cp)"` may work; but if there's more than one `cp` running, it won't work. There is `pidof -s` which returns at most one PID, but you cannot be sure it will belong to the right `cp` process if there are many.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a realtime output of the `lsof` command referenced in [the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66994/70847) by [@gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles-so-stop-being-evil) by using `watch` like this:

```
watch -n1 lsof -p$(pgrep -x cp)
```

The `-n1` flag sets the update interval to 1 second but you can set it to something lower like 0.5 for more accuracy. The default is 2 seconds.

You can also run the `watch` command with `cp` by using an ampersand `&`. For example, to copy `somefile` to `/someplace`, you can do this:

```
cp somefile /someplace & watch lsof -n1 -p$(pgrep -x cp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use [pipeviewer](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml).

```
for f in *; do
  pv $f > destination/$f
done
```

Answer (score 0):

@nachoparker provided a modern way of doing it. If you work on servers and don't have time to implement external things: use `cp --verbose`.

Answer (score 0):

If there are any edge cases like mine who need to display the progress in a GUI, the accepted answer can be adapted to `zenity` pretty easily.

```sh
function cpstat_zenity()
{
  local pid="${1:-$(pgrep -xn cp)}" src dst
  [[ "$pid" ]] || return
  while [[ -f "/proc/$pid/fd/3" ]]; do
    # ignore nuisance stderr messages with 2> /dev/null
    read -r src dst < <(stat -L --printf '%s ' "/proc/$pid/fd/"{3,4} 2> /dev/null)
    (( src )) || break
    # print only an integer for zenity.
    # src + 1 keeps the bar from auto-closing if running on a loop.
    printf '%d\r' $((dst*100/src + 1))
    sleep 0.5
  done
}

cpstat_zenity | zenity  --width=300 --progress --auto-close
```

This can be put in an executable sh script and run straight from the file manager.

This also can be used purposefully like `cp src dst & cpstat_zenity | zenity ...` and also more complex loops.

```sh
function cp_loop()
{
    for file in /some/dir/*.iso; do
        echo "#Copying ${file}..."   # this displays in zenity
        cp "$file" /some/other/dir/ & cpstat_zenity
    done
}

cp_loop | zenity --progress --auto-close --width=300
```

Answer (score -1):

You can send a signal to the process:

```
kill -SIGUSR1 pid
```

It is even  more useful to create a script that polls until you press Ctrl-C or the process finished:

```
while [ : ] ; do kill -SIGUSR1 $1 && sleep 1m || exit ; done
```

**Works for dd. Doesn't work for cp**. Maybe you have to use another signal. I once tried SIGINFO, but it doesn't seem to exist any more on the Intel platform.