# How to check progress of cp when target is a whole-device

Tags: rsync, cp, progress-information

To create a debian install stick, one copies the iso to the device:

```
cp debian-testing-amd64-DVD-1.iso /dev/sdb
```

per this page:

https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/amd64/ch04s03.html.en

according to this SE question:

[How to check progress of running cp?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66795/how-to-check-progress-of-running-cp)

one can monitor the progress using `stat -c "%s" /dev/sdb`

Despite the light flashing activity on the thmubdrive, `stat` is reporting `0`

I tried `rsync`, but `rsync` fails, reports 'no space left on device'

Answer (score 2):

dd would be a more appropriate tool for the job in this case and if you use pipe viewer you can pass the dd command through it.
e.g

`dd if=debian-testing-amd64-DVD-1.iso | pv | dd of=/dev/sdb`

if you use the --size/-s option and specify an approx size it will also try give an approximate time.

`dd if=debian-testing-amd64-DVD-1.iso | pv -s 3G | dd of=/dev/sdb`

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't since `cp` has no monitoring functionality.

The SE question you refer to relies on a filesystem which is not your case.  How could any application know what represents actual data as opposed to random junk present on the drive?