# Backup files with tar command and progress bar?

Tags: shell-script, tar, progress-information

[image]Can I see a progress bar or something not only ust the terminal screen output while backing up?

Here is my shell script that I used backup with `tar` command:

```
# !/bin/bash

 DATEJOUR=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
 REPABACKUPER="--exclude=/home/(username)/myfolders \
 --exclude=/home/(username)/backup                  \
 --exclude=/proc                                    \
 --exclude=/lost+found                              \
 --exclude=/mnt                                     \
 --exclude=/media                                   \
 --exclude=/sys /"
 REPBACKUP="/home/(username)/backup"
 NOMFIC=$REPBACKUP/Pavilion_backup-$DATEJOUR.tar.bz2

 sudo tar cvpjf $NOMFIC $REPABACKUPER


 exit $?
```

Comment: [Here is a shell function](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65087/12779) that combines `tar` and `pv`.

Comment: Thanks all of you.Here is my update and it works. sudo tar -cvpj -f $NOMFIC $REPABACKUPER | pv -cN Backup_Now | tar -xvf -

Answer (score 4):

`pipebench` shows running time, data processed and speed:

```
tar -cj --exclude=filename source_dir | pipebench >dest.tar.bz2
```

Answer (score 3):

That's what I use for backup, the progress bar is powered by `pv` command

```
tar cf - . --exclude=backup --exclude=$file | pv -s `du -sb . | grep -o '[0-9]\+'` -N tar  | gzip > $file
```

`du -sb . | grep -o '[0-9]\+'` this part is responsible for getting 100% in your progress bar

Comment: Your tar is using compression, so `du` isn't going to tell how much data it has to write. (take the *z* off and pipe to `gzip`)

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.  `tar` doesn't know how much data it has to work with until it's done with it.  Unlike `rsync`, it does not scan the source tree before processing.

(During extraction, it's *possible*, but I don't know any versions of tar that bothers.)