# See the overall percentage completion of a recursive cp command

Tags: command-line, pipe, cp

Is it a simple way to track the completion of a large `cp -r` command?
To get something like:

```
copying 10%
...
copying 20%
```

Maybe using a pipe to another command?
`cp -rvv orig dest | show_as_percent`

---

**update**

I've checked [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65077/168539) question, but when I try to copy folder:
`rsync -P source dest`
or
`rsync --progress source dest`
or
`rsync --info=progress2 source dest`

it says: `skipping directory source`

After checking [this](http://lucasb.eyer.be/snips/rsync-skipping-directory.html) resource, I see the `rsync` command working is:
`rsync -r --progress source dest`, great, 
but the output comes as:

```
source/
source/a.c
          4,114 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=3/5)
source/b.c
          5,480 100%    5.23MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#2, to-chk=2/5)
source/c.c
          4,615 100%    4.40MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#3, to-chk=1/5)
```

Is there an easy way to have the overall percentage (and not per file percentage) and a more simple output which can be easily parsed using `awk` for example? 
Looking for a way of getting in console a *nice integer* representing a completion percentage.

Any suggestion in the shape of:
`cp -rvv orig dest | show_as_percent`

Comment: Checkout the command `pv` ;-)

Comment: You could use **rsync** in the next format: `rsync -P /source/ /destination/`, where *-P* option is to show the progress of the rsync copy.

Comment: mmm... `pv` doesn't come as defualt installed in my unix system, solutions should not require an install, as no an easy `apt-get install` is possible. @k.Cyborg, thanks, `rsync -P` looks awesome.

Comment: @Evhz : That comment is totally unfair.  The "pv" command isn't installed by default on many systems, but one likely cause of that would be that it may just be a bit of a newer command.  It's a nice command, useful with way more purposes than rsync, so chances seem pretty good that pv may someday be included in more distributions than rsync is. rsync certainly isn't in my preferred distro by default.  Although rsync is awesome, its inclusion in the operating system that you happen to use (and didn't specify) doesn't make a comment pv more worthy of general ridicule than rsync (for that reason)