# Get a progress indicator when importing MySQL databases

Tags: bash, mysql

I often import MySQL databases, and this can take a while. There is no progress indicator whatsoever. Can one be shown, somehow? Either records imported, MB imported, or tables imported... anything is better than just waiting. Anybody any idea?

I use this command:

`mysql -uuser -p -hhost database < largefile.sql`

Files are between 40-300 MB, and the host is within the local network.

Comment: [Do these (`pv`, `cpipe`) work in this scenario?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1537/measure-pipe-throughput-in-the-shell/1539#1539)

Comment: @sr_ I think `pv` is exactly what the questioner searches for. I just installed it on CentOS via rpmforge. If given the **size**-parameter it will even show an ETA.

Comment: `pv` did the trick indeed! If somebody can make this an answer, I can accept this!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There is a nice tool called `pv`.

```
# On Ubuntu/Debian system
$ sudo apt-get install pv

# On Redhat/CentOS
$ sudo yum install pv
```

then e.g. you can use it like this

```
$ zcat dbpackfile.sql.gz | pv -cN zcat | mysql -uuser -ppass dbname
```

> NOTE: Please check this blog
> http://blog.larsstrand.no/2011/12/tip-pipe-viewer.html for more
> insights.
>
> NOTE: Even better solution with FULL progress bar. To do it you
> have to use two build-in `pv` options. One is `--progress` to indicate
> the progress bar and the second is `--size` to tell `pv` how large the
> overall file is.
>
> ```
> pv --progress --size UNPACKED-FILE-SIZE-IN-BYTES
> ```

..the problem is with `.gz` original file size. You need somehow get unpacked original file size information without unpacking itself, otherwise, you will lose precious time to unpack this file twice (first time for `pv` and second time for `zcat`). But fortunately, you have `gzip -l` option that contains uncompressed information about our gzipped file. Unfortunately, it is in a table format so you need to extract it before it can be used it. All together can be seen below:

```
gzip -l /path/to/our/database.sql.gz | sed -n 2p | awk '{print $2}'
```

> NOTE: This is the list of most common archive tools and methods how to extract a number of uncompressed bytes from those archives:
>
> ```
>  tar -tvf database.sql.tar | awk '{print $3}' | paste -sd+ | bc
>
>  unzip -Zt database.sql.zip | awk '{print $3}'
>
>  unrar l database.sql.rar | tail -n2 | head -n1 | awk '{ print $1 }'
>
>  7z l database.sql.7z | tail -n1 | awk '{ print $3 }'
> ```

Uff.. so the last thing you need to do is just combine it all together.

```
zcat /path/to/our/database.sql.gz | pv --progress --size `gzip -l %s | sed -n 2p | awk '{print $2}'` | mysql -uuser -ppass dbname
```

To make it even nicer you can add progress NAME like this

```
zcat /path/to/our/database.sql.gz | pv --progress --size `gzip -l %s | sed -n 2p | awk '{print $2}'` --name '  Importing.. ' | mysql -uuser -ppass dbname
```

Final result:

```
Importing.. : [===========================================>] 100%
```

For quick usage, you can create a custom function.

```
mysql_import() {
  zcat $2 | pv --progress --size `gzip -l %s | sed -n 2p | awk '{print $2}'` --name '  Importing.. ' | mysql -uuser -ppass $1
}
```

..and then use it like this:

```
mysql_import dbname /path/to/our/database.sql.gz
```

> NOTE: If you don't know where to put it, read this answer:
> https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/106606/20056

> NOTE: You can add functions among aliases, e.g. in `~/.bash_aliases` file.

Comment: this is awesome.

Comment: A one liner with a better result is this can be this: ```pv --progress --name 'DB Import in progress' -tea /path/to/our/database.sql.gz | zcat | mysql -h db_host -u db_user -pdb_password db_name```

Answer (score 39):

Why so complicated ?

This works fine :

```
pv dump.sql.gz | zcat | mysql -u user -ppasswd database
```

Comment: Much simpler and cleaner!

Comment: My first example is almost the same

Answer (score 13):

I always import databases from the MySql shell. It does not provide a progress indicator, but it does (quickly) scroll the actions it is performing so I know it's working.

```
# mysql -u user -p -h host database
> source /path/to/some/largefile.sql;
```

Answer (score 5):

[sobi3ch's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41199/342001) is great for most situations, but Pipe Viewer doesn't work well in use cases where a tty isn't available, like when monitoring a mysql docker container's initialization output or when you want to log the progress to a file.

**Pipe Monitor** ([github](https://github.com/SoftCoil/pipe-monitor)) is an alternative designed to output updates to a log stream via STDERR. Disclaimer: I am the author.

Their basic functionality is very similar: Read from STDIN or a file. Pipe the contents to STDOUT. Show progress. However, whereas Pipe View uses terminal control sequences to update a visual progress bar on a single line, Pipe Monitor outputs text updates appropriate for non terminal applications.

Pipe Monitor supports the following basic options. Output is customizable via the --format option:

```
Usage: pm [--size SIZE] [--name NAME] [--format FORMAT] INPUT_FILE

Positional arguments:
  INPUT_FILE             Optional input file. If not provided input will be read from STDIN

Options:
  --size SIZE, -s SIZE   Size of input from STDIN. Ignored if using INPUT_FILE
  --name NAME, -n NAME   A NAME tag for this output. Will be pre-pended to default FORMAT string
  --format FORMAT, -f FORMAT
                         Output format string. Allowed keys: %name, %size, %time, %eta, %percent, %written, %buffered
  --help, -h             display this help and exit
```

Here is a comparison of the output of each in a non terminal environment.

Pipe Viewer (non terminal):

```
$ pv -nf testin > testout
40
70
77
84
90
96
100
```

Pipe Monitor:

```
$ pm testin > testout
Processed 0 bytes of 2456678400 (0% complete). 0 bytes buffered. Running 0s, eta: <unknown>
Processed 1750794240 bytes of 2456678400 (71% complete). 327680 bytes buffered. Running 2s, eta: 1s
Processed 2106937344 bytes of 2456678400 (85% complete). 700416 bytes buffered. Running 4s, eta: 1s
Processed 2419339264 bytes of 2456678400 (98% complete). 2871296 bytes buffered. Running 6s, eta: 0s
Processed 2456678400 bytes of 2456678400 (100% complete). 0 bytes buffered. Running 6s, eta: 0s
```

Comment: Really nice work! I gave your project a star and upvote your answer.

Comment: @sobi3ch, thank you for the support :-)