# Pass output of "whereis" command to "cd" to change directory in one step

Tags: bash, command-line, cd-command, command-substitution

I can't find a way to pass output of `whereis` command to `cd` command in same line so I don't have to do `cd` in the second step.

I have tried passing like below:

```
cd $(whereis node_modules)
```

Or

```
cd "`dirname $(whereis node_modules)`"
```

Also

```
cd "$(whereis node_modules)"
```

But none of the above method works.

Can somebody find what should be wrong in above codes ?

Comment: What is the output of yor second command?

Comment: `bash: cd: .
/usr/local/lib: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that with,

```
cd "`which node_modules`"
```

With `dirname` to get the directory:

```
cd "$(dirname "$(which node_modules)" )"
```

as you have mentioned in the comment *I am expecting to do this in one step* &  assuming `nod_module` is a directory, so you can do that with the following command:

```
cd $(whereis node_modules | cut -d ' ' -f2)
```

(Note that the latter command assumes that the Linux `whereis` is being used, not the BSD one, and that the path does not contain any spaces.)

As suggested by @Dani_I, you can have a look at this [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then), which might be more useful.

Comment: No, these doesn't work either, `cd $(which node_modules | xargs dirname)` gives me `missing operand` error.

Comment: @VickyDev are you sure ? I tested same command replacing `node_modules` with `find` and it `cd` to dir

Comment: Yes I tried it several times, but it gives me `missing operand` error

Comment: `missing operand` means that you specified a command which `which` could not find on your system.  Try a different command, one that `which` can locate.

Comment: @John1024 as OP have specified `ubuntu` in tag, assuming that, it should have `which` command, what you say ?

Comment: @Rahul Yes, I expect that `which` is installed.  I don't have node_modules installed but I tried your command for firefox: `cd $(which firefox | xargs dirname)` __and it worked fine__.  When I tried it with a bad name, say `cd $(which firefoxx | xargs dirname)` then it returns `missing operand` which is the same error that VickyDev reports.

Comment: Doing `which node_modules` give me empty string, but doing `whereis node_modules` gives me `node_modules: /usr/local/lib/node_modules`, so how can I `cd` to that path (removing colon and everything before it) in same step ?

Comment: @VickyDev see my updated answer

Comment: That works, thanks, so it will work for any `whereis` directory path which have a colon and directory name before it right ?, Generalised ? If yes then I will at-once accept it.

Comment: @VickyDev remember `dirname` is used to *strip last component from file name*. so it depends on your system. Because when I use the same command `whereis find` it gives me `find: /usr/bin/find`, but I can't `cd` to `/usr/bin/find`  it will give me error like 'No such file' because last component of `whereis` result `find` is not a directory. so I had to use `dirname` along with `cd$(..)` to change directory.

Comment: It won't work if there are multiple paths(space delimited), I get that, but it should work if there is only one path location of any component/command/directory, right ? I guess that's about it then.

Comment: Oh no, problem is there, I have also installed `bower` it is installed only in one path `/usr/local/bin/bower` but when I use your command like `cd $(whereis bower | cut -d ' ' -f2)` it gives me `bash: cd: /usr/local/bin/bower: Not a directory` error.

Comment: @VickyDev at that time you would have to use `cd $(whereis bower  | cut -d ' ' -f2 | xargs dirname)`

Comment: @VickyDev as I told you, it depends on your system, `dirname` is used to strip last component of path. previous command gave you error because `bower` is not a directory.

Comment: @Rahul, got that, thanks a lot, your last answer (the one with `find`) is really re-usable and generalised

Comment: you should probably replace `which` with `command -v` and see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then

Answer (score 6):

This appears to do the trick:

```
cd "$(dirname "$(whereis node_modules)")"
```

If, as per your comment, you want to go *into* the target if it is a directory:

```
location=$(whereis node_modules)
if [[ -d "$location" ]]; then
    cd "$location"
else
    cd "$(dirname "$location" )"
fi
```

The above could easily be made into a function in your `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Nope, sorry it doesn't work,  doing `whereis node_modules` gives me path `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` but doing `cd` like you did doesn't put me in that directory path.

Comment: Try `cd $(dirname $(whereis node_modules | cut -d' ' -f2) )`

Comment: Very close, but it goes to `/usr/local/lib` but stays out of `node_modules`.

Comment: That's because the command I gave you (for which you asked) goes to the directory in which the specified thing you searched for resides.  `ls` is at `/bin/ls`, so `cd $(dirname $(whereis ls) )` will resolve to `cd /bin`.  I will adjust my answer to go into a directory if that is what you have specified.

Comment: @DopeGhoti, many thanks to you for suggesting an alternate way. Can you post links for how to create function in `.bash_profile` in your answer ?

Comment: @VickyDev [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106601/how-to-add-a-function-to-bash-profile-profile-bashrc-in-shell) will surely help you.

Answer (score 4):

`whereis` gives you the pattern name and the location, separated by colon, so performing `cd` or `dirname` on `whereis` result can not work:

```
$ whereis node_modules
node_modules: /usr/lib/node_modules
```

The proper method is using `npm` itself to get its default prefix:

```
$ cd "$(npm get prefix)/lib/node_modules"
$ pwd
/usr/lib/node_modules
```

Comment: Your answer is good, thanks, but I was expecting to do it in same step, can't we just remove everything before first colon including colon and pass it to `cd`, string operation on the output of command just like in other languages ?

Comment: What do you mean *one step*? Is not `cd "$(npm get prefix)/lib/node_modules"` one step only?

Comment: But when I don't know the whole path and just last directory name then how would I use your command ? It's not just about the `node_modules` dir but generalised for any directory in my system

Comment: It depends on your tool. Here you want to get to `npm` default modules location, then it's always `npm` prefix + `lib/node_modules`, other tools need other method.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Where is has -q (quite) option, which is just for the purpose of passing result in command line.

```
cd `whereis -q node_modules`
```